# Multi-dimensional arrays in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, multidimensional-array

I am planning a script to manage some pieces of my Linux systems and am at the point of deciding if I want to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or [python](/questions/tagged/python).

I would prefer to do this as a Bash script simply because the commands are easier, but the real deciding factor is configuration.  I need to be able to store a multi-dimensional array in the configuration file to tell the script what to do with itself.  Storing simple key=value pairs in config files is easy enough with bash, but the only way I can think of to do a multi-dimensional array is a two layer parsing engine, something like

```
array=&d1|v1;v2;v3&d2|v1;v2;v3
```

but the marshall/unmarshall code could get to be a bear and its far from user friendly for the next poor sap that has to administer this.  If i can't do this easily in bash i will simply write the configs to an xml file and write the script in python.

Is there an easy way to do this in bash?

thanks everyone.

Comment: Related: [How to declare 2D array in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16487258/55075)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Bash does not support multidimensional arrays, nor hashes, and it seems that you want a hash that values are arrays. This solution is not very beautiful, a solution with an xml file should be better :

```
array=('d1=(v1 v2 v3)' 'd2=(v1 v2 v3)')
for elt in "${array[@]}";do eval $elt;done
echo "d1 ${#d1[@]} ${d1[@]}"
echo "d2 ${#d2[@]} ${d2[@]}"
```

EDIT: this answer is quite old, since since bash 4 supports hash tables, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828958/how-do-format-and-traverse-an-array-that-contains-arrays-and-each-array-contain/44831174#44831174) for a solution without eval.

Comment: Just a note. bash does support hashes (associative arrays) starting from version 4. more info: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: FYI associative arrays can have some of the 'declare' attributes set on them, such as 'set to uppercase on assignment' however, they cannot have the -A [associative] or -a [numeric] array set to them, nor the -n reference set, but you CAN tag your variable name with a number, and use a variable in place: MYARR_$i_[$j] would be the closest thing to this, however it isnt a true md array, but this is the best you are going to get. You could also use functions as a pseudo-array system if you were desperate enough :)

Comment: and there it is... evil... sorry i meant eval

Comment: You could always `declare -a "$elt"` instead of `eval $elt`.

Comment: @ghoti, yes the answer is quite old, another similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831174/1454708, I supposed that the OP knows what he is doing and input is checked

Answer (score 35):

Bash doesn't have multi-dimensional array. But you can simulate a somewhat similar effect with associative arrays. The following is an example of associative array pretending to be used as multi-dimensional array:

```
declare -A arr
arr[0,0]=0
arr[0,1]=1
arr[1,0]=2
arr[1,1]=3
echo "${arr[0,0]} ${arr[0,1]}" # will print 0 1
```

If you don't declare the array as associative (with `-A`), the above won't work. For example, if you omit the `declare -A arr` line, the `echo` will print `2 3` instead of `0 1`, because `0,0`, `1,0` and such will be taken as arithmetic expression and evaluated to `0` (the value to the right of the comma operator).

Comment: declare -A [arrayname] elicits an "invalid option", at least in OS X.

Comment: EDIT: It appears OS X comes with bash 3 and this option requires bash 4. Thanks, Apple.

Answer (score 26):

This works thanks to 1. "indirect expansion" with ! which adds one layer of indirection, and 2. "substring expansion" which behaves differently with arrays and can be used to "slice" them as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336245/317623

```
# Define each array and then add it to the main one
SUB_0=("name0" "value 0")
SUB_1=("name1" "value;1")
MAIN_ARRAY=(
  SUB_0[@]
  SUB_1[@]
)

# Loop and print it.  Using offset and length to extract values
COUNT=${#MAIN_ARRAY[@]}
for ((i=0; i<$COUNT; i++))
do
  NAME=${!MAIN_ARRAY[i]:0:1}
  VALUE=${!MAIN_ARRAY[i]:1:1}
  echo "NAME ${NAME}"
  echo "VALUE ${VALUE}"
done
```

It's based off of [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179474/30901)

Comment: it should be `NAME=${!MAIN_ARRAY[i]:0:1}` and `VALUE=${!MAIN_ARRAY[i]:1:1}` if I'm not mistaken for this to work (ie. exchange `URLS` for `MAIN`).

Comment: I haven't yet looked into why - but this works fine on bash v4.3+ but has trouble with earlier versions. (prints individual characters instead of full words)

Comment: I wish with would work without having to define `SUB_0` and `SUB_1` before `MAIN_ARRAY`

Comment: @dtmland what seems to happen with older bash versions is plain substring expansion instead of the array slicing alternative.

Comment: If you have to define literal names with the index like SUB_0 and SUB_1 it is not really a 'universal' multidimensional array.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use a bash script and keep it easy to read recommend putting the data in structured JSON, and then use [lightweight tool jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in your bash command to iterate through the array.  For example with the following dataset:

```
[

    {"specialId":"123",
    "specialName":"First"},

    {"specialId":"456",
    "specialName":"Second"},

    {"specialId":"789",
    "specialName":"Third"}
]
```

You can iterate through this data with a bash script and jq like this:

```
function loopOverArray(){

    jq -c '.[]' testing.json | while read i; do
        # Do stuff here
        echo "$i"
    done
}

loopOverArray
```

Outputs:

```
{"specialId":"123","specialName":"First"}
{"specialId":"456","specialName":"Second"}
{"specialId":"789","specialName":"Third"}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Definitely the easiest of the pragmatic solutions.  We can leave the purity to the purists.

Answer (score 8):

Independent of the shell being used (sh, ksh, bash, ...) the following approach works pretty well for n-dimensional arrays (the sample covers a 2-dimensional array).

In the sample the line-separator (1st dimension) is the space character. For introducing a field separator (2nd dimension) the standard unix tool `tr` is used. Additional separators for additional dimensions can be used in the same way.

Of course the performance of this approach is not very well, but if performance is not a criteria this approach is quite generic and can solve many problems:

```
array2d="1.1:1.2:1.3 2.1:2.2 3.1:3.2:3.3:3.4"

function process2ndDimension {
    for dimension2 in $*
    do
        echo -n $dimension2 "   "
    done
    echo
}

function process1stDimension {
    for dimension1 in $array2d
    do
        process2ndDimension `echo $dimension1 | tr : " "`
    done
}

process1stDimension
```

The output of that sample looks like this:

```
1.1     1.2     1.3     
2.1     2.2     
3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
```

Comment: Doesn't work very well if the values contain spaces or colons, though. :)

Comment: @dannysauer - should be fine if you encode spaces and colons as an entity or hex code. %20 and %3a for example. It should be easy enough to process input to and output from the array through such functions if that's a concern for you.

Comment: So then the values don't contain spaces or colons. :D

Comment: Can I have one loop and one function instead of two?

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of trial and error i actually find the best, clearest and easiest multidimensional array on bash is to use a regular var. Yep.

Advantages: You don't have to loop through a big array, you can just echo "$var" and use grep/awk/sed. It's easy and clear and you can have as many columns as you like.

Example:

```
$ var=$(echo -e 'kris hansen oslo\nthomas jonson peru\nbibi abu johnsonville\njohnny lipp peru')

$ echo "$var"
kris hansen oslo
thomas johnson peru
bibi abu johnsonville
johnny lipp peru
```

## If you want to find everyone in peru

```
$ echo "$var" | grep peru
thomas johnson peru
johnny lipp peru
```

## Only grep(sed) in the third field

```
$ echo "$var" | sed -n -E '/(.+) (.+) peru/p'
thomas johnson peru
johnny lipp peru
```

## If you only want x field

```
$ echo "$var" | awk '{print $2}'
hansen
johnson
abu
johnny
```

## Everyone in peru that's called thomas and just return his lastname

```
$ echo "$var" |grep peru|grep thomas|awk '{print $2}'
johnson
```

Any query you can think of... supereasy.

## To change an item:

```
$ var=$(echo "$var"|sed "s/thomas/pete/")
```

## To delete a row that contains "x"

```
$ var=$(echo "$var"|sed "/thomas/d")
```

## To change another field in the same row based on a value from another item

```
$ var=$(echo "$var"|sed -E "s/(thomas) (.+) (.+)/\1 test \3/")
$ echo "$var"
kris hansen oslo                                                                                                                                             
thomas test peru                                                                                                                                          
bibi abu johnsonville
johnny lipp peru
```

## Of course looping works too if you want to do that

```
$ for i in "$var"; do echo "$i"; done
kris hansen oslo
thomas jonson peru
bibi abu johnsonville
johnny lipp peru
```

The only gotcha iv'e found with this is that you *must* always quote the 
var(in the example; both var and i) or things will look like this

```
$ for i in "$var"; do echo $i; done
kris hansen oslo thomas jonson peru bibi abu johnsonville johnny lipp peru
```

and someone will undoubtedly say it won't work if you have spaces in your input, however that can be fixed by using another delimeter in your input, eg(using an utf8 char now to emphasize that you can choose something your input won't contain, but you can choose whatever ofc):

```
$ var=$(echo -e 'field one☥field two hello☥field three yes moin\nfield 1☥field 2☥field 3 dsdds aq')

$ for i in "$var"; do echo "$i"; done
field one☥field two hello☥field three yes moin
field 1☥field 2☥field 3 dsdds aq

$ echo "$var" | awk -F '☥' '{print $3}'
field three yes moin
field 3 dsdds aq

$ var=$(echo "$var"|sed -E "s/(field one)☥(.+)☥(.+)/\1☥test☥\3/")
$ echo "$var"
field one☥test☥field three yes moin
field 1☥field 2☥field 3 dsdds aq
```

If you want to store newlines in your input, you could convert the newline to something else before input and convert it back again on output(or don't use bash...). Enjoy!

Comment: This may work for two dimensions, but for a generic case with n dimensions this is getting hard.

Comment: That's true. When i wrote this i didn't realise the difference between 2d, 3d, 4d and all i'd ever needed was good tabular support/db. Now, I still haven't needed anything more than 2d, but if one needs more then i suppose this won't work.

Comment: "Of course looping works too if you want to do that" - your looping example isn't doing what you think it's doing. It's processing one single value, the entire array, at once, rather than each item in the array. Eg try `for i in "$var"; do echo "row=$i"; done` and you'll see only one row.

Answer (score 4):

I am posting the following because it is a very simple and clear way to mimic (at least to some extent) the behavior of a two-dimensional array in Bash. It uses a here-file (see the Bash manual) and `read` (a Bash builtin command):

```
## Store the "two-dimensional data" in a file ($$ is just the process ID of the shell, to make sure the filename is unique)
cat > physicists.$$ <<EOF
Wolfgang Pauli 1900
Werner Heisenberg 1901
Albert Einstein 1879
Niels Bohr 1885
EOF
nbPhysicists=$(wc -l physicists.$$ | cut -sf 1 -d ' ')     # Number of lines of the here-file specifying the physicists.

## Extract the needed data
declare -a person     # Create an indexed array (necessary for the read command).                                                                                 
while read -ra person; do
    firstName=${person[0]}
    familyName=${person[1]}
    birthYear=${person[2]}
    echo "Physicist ${firstName} ${familyName} was born in ${birthYear}"
    # Do whatever you need with data
done < physicists.$$

## Remove the temporary file
rm physicists.$$
```

Output:
 `Physicist Wolfgang Pauli was born in 1900 Physicist Werner Heisenberg was born in 1901 Physicist Albert Einstein was born in 1879 Physicist Niels Bohr was born in 1885`

**The way it works:**

- The lines in the temporary file created play the role of one-dimensional vectors, where the blank spaces (or whatever separation character you choose; see the description of the `read` command in the Bash manual) separate the elements of these vectors.
- Then, using the `read` command with its `-a` option, we loop over each line of the file (until we reach end of file). For each line, we can assign the desired fields (= words) to an array, which we declared just before the loop. The `-r` option to the `read` command prevents backslashes from acting as escape characters, in case we typed backslashes in the here-document `physicists.$$`.

In conclusion a file is created as a 2D-array, and its elements are extracted using a loop over each line, and using the ability of the `read` command to assign words to the elements of an (indexed) array.

**Slight improvement:**

In the above code, the file `physicists.$$` is given as input to the `while` loop, so that it is in fact passed to the `read` command. However, I found that this causes problems when I have another command asking for input inside the `while` loop. For example, the `select` command waits for standard input, and if placed inside the `while` loop, it will take input from `physicists.$$`, instead of prompting in the command-line for user input.
To correct this, I use the `-u` option of `read`, which allows to read from a file descriptor. We only have to create a file descriptor (with the `exec` command) corresponding to `physicists.$$` and to give it to the `-u` option of read, as in the following code:

```
## Store the "two-dimensional data" in a file ($$ is just the process ID of the shell, to make sure the filename is unique)
cat > physicists.$$ <<EOF
Wolfgang Pauli 1900
Werner Heisenberg 1901
Albert Einstein 1879
Niels Bohr 1885
EOF
nbPhysicists=$(wc -l physicists.$$ | cut -sf 1 -d ' ')     # Number of lines of the here-file specifying the physicists.
exec {id_file}<./physicists.$$     # Create a file descriptor stored in 'id_file'.

## Extract the needed data
declare -a person     # Create an indexed array (necessary for the read command).                                                                                 
while read -ra person -u "${id_file}"; do
firstName=${person[0]}
familyName=${person[1]}
birthYear=${person[2]}
echo "Physicist ${firstName} ${familyName} was born in ${birthYear}"
# Do whatever you need with data
done

## Close the file descriptor
exec {id_file}<&-
## Remove the temporary file
rm physicists.$$
```

Notice that the file descriptor is closed at the end.

Comment: It's very much the same as user7909577's solution. However what you do is write a sequence of lines in a text file. So the dimension 1 is the line number. Dimension 2 is the word in a line.
A truely generic solution, however, would allow to put any array in any array. And that won't work. OK, you could implement dimensions by indenting the lines, but that's still not very elegant.

Comment: @U. Windi "put any array in any array. And that won't work.": That's why I stress in my answer that it is to simulate 2D-ARRAYS. "It's very much the same as user7909577's solution": I don't think so, he/she parses a string with sed/grep/awk in his answer, and I do it by "transforming" the string into an array first, then using indices (that is why it simulates the behaviour of an array).

Comment: @Guiseppe: But both solutions use a text file as representation for a two dimensional array with the dimensions as I had described. The question specifically was about _multi_-dimensional arrays (There's a separate question for two-dimensional arrays).

Comment: @U. Windl: I agree, but as I understand user7909577's solution, it's never really an array that you have, but a long list where you have to put separators (like newline). So each time you start a new loop, you are stuck with one element of your long list. On the contrary with my solution, at each loop you work with a real 1D-array (a line of the simulated 2D-array), and you can therefore access any of its elements, which is much more convenient in my opinion. I didn't notice the other question on two-dimensional arrays, so if you know how to move answers I am interested.

Answer (score 3):

Bash does not supports multidimensional array, but we can implement using Associate array. Here the indexes are the key to retrieve the value. Associate array is available in `bash` version 4.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr2d
rows=3
columns=2

for ((i=0;i<rows;i++)) do
    for ((j=0;j<columns;j++)) do
        arr2d[$i,$j]=$i
    done
done


for ((i=0;i<rows;i++)) do
    for ((j=0;j<columns;j++)) do
        echo ${arr2d[$i,$j]}
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Paul's answer - here's my version of working with associative sub-arrays in bash:

```
declare -A SUB_1=(["name1key"]="name1val" ["name2key"]="name2val")
declare -A SUB_2=(["name3key"]="name3val" ["name4key"]="name4val")
STRING_1="string1val"
STRING_2="string2val"
MAIN_ARRAY=(
  "${SUB_1[*]}"
  "${SUB_2[*]}"
  "${STRING_1}"
  "${STRING_2}"
)
echo "COUNT: " ${#MAIN_ARRAY[@]}
for key in ${!MAIN_ARRAY[@]}; do
    IFS=' ' read -a val <<< ${MAIN_ARRAY[$key]}
    echo "VALUE: " ${val[@]}
    if [[ ${#val[@]} -gt 1 ]]; then
        for subkey in ${!val[@]}; do
            subval=${val[$subkey]}
            echo "SUBVALUE: " ${subval}
        done
    fi
done
```

It works with mixed values in the main array - strings/arrays/assoc. arrays

The key here is to wrap the subarrays in single quotes and use `*` instead of `@` when storing a subarray inside the main array so it would get stored as a single, space separated string: `"${SUB_1[*]}"`

Then it makes it easy to parse an array out of that when looping through values with `IFS=' ' read -a val <<< ${MAIN_ARRAY[$key]}`

The code above outputs:

```
COUNT:  4
VALUE:  name1val name2val
SUBVALUE:  name1val
SUBVALUE:  name2val
VALUE:  name4val name3val
SUBVALUE:  name4val
SUBVALUE:  name3val
VALUE:  string1val
VALUE:  string2val
```

Comment: So you can't store strings that contain spaces (not mentioning newlines). Also your lack of quotes makes it impossible to safely have glob characters.

Comment: Yes, I've just realised it will break down strings with spaces into separate sub-values, but I, personally can live with that if it's just config values... But I think that's about the best that we can do in bash. I'm open to suggestions/improvements though. Added the quotes, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Hi, can you explain how does `IFS=' ' read -a val <<< ${MAIN_ARRAY[$key]}` work. What is IFS? Is it an variable being defined there? Why read is appended to the variable definition?

Comment: @CharlesW. See  [Bash Reference Manual, 5.1 Bourne Shell Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS): "`IFS` – A list of characters that separate fields; used when the shell splits words as part of expansion." and [6.7 Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays): "If the word is double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the `IFS` variable, ...".

Answer (score 2):

Lots of answers found here for creating multidimensional arrays in bash.

And without exception, all are obtuse and difficult to use.

If MD arrays are a required criteria, it is time to make a decision:

**Use a language that supports MD arrays**

My preference is Perl.  Most would probably choose Python.
Either works.

**Store the data elsewhere**

JSON and jq have already been suggested.  XML has also been suggested, though for your use JSON and jq would likely be simpler.

It would seem though that Bash may not be the best choice for what you need to do.

Sometimes the correct question is not "How do I do X in tool Y?", but rather "Which tool would be best to do X?"

Answer (score 1):

I do this using **associative arrays** since **bash 4** and setting **`IFS`** to a value that can be defined manually.

The purpose of this approach is to have arrays as values of associative array keys.

In order to set IFS back to default just unset it.

- `unset IFS`

---

This is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# used as value in asscciative array
test=(
  "x3:x4:x5"
)
# associative array
declare -A wow=(
  ["1"]=$test
  ["2"]=$test
)
echo "default IFS"
for w in ${wow[@]}; do
  echo "  $w"
done

IFS=:
echo "IFS=:"
for w in ${wow[@]}; do
  for t in $w; do
    echo "  $t"
  done
done
echo -e "\n or\n"
for w in ${!wow[@]}
do
  echo "  $w"
  for t in ${wow[$w]}
  do
    echo "    $t"
  done
done

unset IFS
unset w
unset t
unset wow
unset test
```

The output of the script below is:

```
default IFS
  x3:x4:x5
  x3:x4:x5
IFS=:
  x3
  x4
  x5
  x3
  x4
  x5

 or

  1
    x3
    x4
    x5
  2
    x3
    x4
    x5
```

Comment: I see no reason to use `test=("x3:x4:x5")` when you reference it as `$test`: You could simply do `test="x3:x4:x5"` .

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU bash, version 5.2.2(1)-release`

I needed to loop through multiple Associate arrays within a single Indexed array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A bch=( [port]="8432" [node]="bchd-node" )
declare -A btc=( [port]="8332" [node]="bitcoind-node" )
declare -a currencies=(bch btc)

for ((i=0; i<"${#currencies[*]}"; i++)); do
    curr="${currencies[$i]}"
    port="${curr}[port]"
    node="${curr}[node]"
    echo "${curr} port is ${!port} -- ${curr} node is ${!node}"
done
```

Result:

```
bch port is 8432 -- bch node is bchd-node
btc port is 8332 -- btc node is bitcoind-node
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a pretty simple yet smart workaround:
Just define the array with variables in its name. For example:

```
for (( i=0 ; i<$(($maxvalue + 1)) ; i++ ))
  do
  for (( j=0 ; j<$(($maxargument + 1)) ; j++ ))
    do
    declare -a array$i[$j]=((Your rule))
  done
done
```

Don't know whether this helps since it's not exactly what you asked for, but it works for me. (The same could be achieved just with variables without the array)

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe people went such far ways for this primary arithmetic:

```
${a[i*w+j]}
```

`a`: A normal array.
`w`: Width of the first dimension.
`i,j`: 0-based indices.
No need to use `$` inside `[]`.

Of course, 3D array would be:

```
${a[(i*w1+j)*w2+k]}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to declare a list of lists and extract values from the list in list.

```
list1=( "value1" "value2" )
list2=( "vlaue3" "value4" )
list3=( "value5" "value6" )
lists=( ${!list1@} ${!list2@} ${!list3@} )
COUNT="${#lists[@]}"
  for ((i=0; i<$COUNT; i++))
    do
      FIRST_VALUE=${lists[$i]}
      FIRST_VALUE=$( eval echo '${'$FIRST_VALUE'[0]}' )
      echo "${FIRST_VALUE}"
      SECOND_VALUE=${lists[$i]}
      SECOND_VALUE=$( eval echo '${'$SECOND_VALUE'[1]}' )
      echo "${SECOND_VALUE}"
    done;
```

Answer (score -4):

```sh
echo "Enter no of terms"
read count
for i in $(seq 1 $count)
do
  t=` expr $i - 1 `
  for j in $(seq $t -1 0)
  do
    echo -n " "
  done
  j=` expr $count + 1 `
  x=` expr $j - $i `
  for k in $(seq 1 $x)
  do
    echo -n "* "
  done
  echo ""
done
```

Comment: Mind to add some explaining words on what the code is supposed to do? While some formatting is helpful as well, some comments would improve the answer even more. Though I can see multiple arrays, I see no multi-dimensional array here.