# How to declare 2D array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm wondering how to declare a 2D array in bash and then initialize to 0.

In C it looks like this:

```
int a[4][5] = {0};
```

And how do I assign a value to an element? As in C:

```
a[2][3] = 3;
```

Comment: Related: [multi-dimensional arrays in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11233825/2533433)

Comment: Btw a multi-dimensional array is actually (deep down) a one dimensional array, which is handled a little bit different especially when it comes to accessing its elements. For example a 3x4 matrix has 12 cells. The "rows" you traverse with an outer loop with a step of 3 and the "columns" you traverse with an inner loop with a step of 1.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can simulate them for example with hashes, but need care about the leading zeroes and many other things. The next demonstration works, but it is far from optimal solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A matrix
num_rows=4
num_columns=5

for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<=num_columns;j++)) do
        matrix[$i,$j]=$RANDOM
    done
done

f1="%$((${#num_rows}+1))s"
f2=" %9s"

printf "$f1" ''
for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
    printf "$f2" $i
done
echo

for ((j=1;j<=num_columns;j++)) do
    printf "$f1" $j
    for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
        printf "$f2" ${matrix[$i,$j]}
    done
    echo
done
```

the above example creates a 4x5 matrix with random numbers and print it transposed, with the example result

```
           1         2         3         4
 1     18006     31193     16110     23297
 2     26229     19869      1140     19837
 3      8192      2181     25512      2318
 4      3269     25516     18701      7977
 5     31775     17358      4468     30345
```

The principle is: Creating one associative array where the index is an string like `3,4`. The benefits:

- it's possible to use for any-dimension arrays ;) like: `30,40,2` for 3 dimensional.
- the syntax is close to "C" like arrays  `${matrix[2,3]}`

Comment: the obvious disadvantage of this method is that the length of a dimension cannot be known. Nonetheless, it works great in most other scenarios! Thanks!!

Comment: Please can you explain what `f1` and `f2` do?

Comment: @Jodes the `f1` and `f2` contains the `format` for the `printf` for the nice aligned printing. It could be hardcoded, for example `printf "%2s"` but using variables are more flexible - as in the above `f1`. The `width` of the *row number* is calculated as the length of `$num_rows` variable - e.g. if the number of rows `$num_rows` is 9, its length is `1` the format will be `1+1` so `%2s`. For the `$num_rows` 2500, its length is `4` so the format will be `%5s` - and so on...

Comment: Faced a big issue implementing this mehtod when it came to modifying array elements. E.g. for `matrix[1,1]=0; matrix[2,1]=0; matrix[1,1]=1;` you expect element `matrix[2,1]` keep `0` but in fact it comes `1`. In other words, attempt to change element by one column index you modify all rows on that column index which is frustrating

Comment: @mechanic You forgot the `declare`. So this: `declare -A matrix; matrix[1,1]=0; matrix[2,1]=0; matrix[1,1]=1; printf ${matrix[2,1]}` prints `0` as it should.

Comment: I am using bash, so If I am using "declare -A", then It is showing me the following error: "Invalid option." and If instead of "declare -A", If I am using "declare -a", then It is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: @nakli_batman strange, because with `-a` it should **not** work. The lowercase `-a` declares an indexed array and for my solution is **NEEDED** tha associative array (which is declared by uppercase `-A`). Strange (old?)`bash` if it doesn't knows the `-A` and even more strange if the lowercase "working fine" :) :)

Answer (score 39):

Bash doesn't have multi-dimensional array. But you can simulate a somewhat similar effect with associative arrays. The following is an example of associative array pretending to be used as multi-dimensional array:

```
declare -A arr
arr[0,0]=0
arr[0,1]=1
arr[1,0]=2
arr[1,1]=3
echo "${arr[0,0]} ${arr[0,1]}" # will print 0 1
```

If you don't declare the array as associative (with `-A`), the above won't work. For example, if you omit the `declare -A arr` line, the `echo` will print `2 3` instead of `0 1`, because `0,0`, `1,0` and such will be taken as arithmetic expression and evaluated to `0` (the value to the right of the comma operator).

Answer (score 25):

Bash does not support multidimensional arrays.

You can simulate it though by using indirect expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a a0=(1 2 3 4)
declare -a a1=(5 6 7 8)
var="a1[1]"
echo ${!var}  # outputs 6
```

Assignments are also possible with this method:

```
let $var=55
echo ${a1[1]}  # outputs 55
```

**Edit 1**: To read such an array from a file, with each row on a line, and values delimited by space, use this:

```
idx=0
while read -a a$idx; do
    let idx++;
done </tmp/some_file
```

**Edit 2**: To declare **and** initialize `a0..a3[0..4]` to `0`, you could run:

```
for i in {0..3}; do
    eval "declare -a a$i=( $(for j in {0..4}; do echo 0; done) )"
done
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to fill the above "2d array simulation" from a file-table? e.g. having a file with random number of rows and in each row containing 5 space delimited numbers.

Comment: @kobame: I edited the answer to provide a solution for what you're asking. It will read a 2d array with a variable number of rows and variable number of columns, into a0, a1 and so on.

Comment: How would you use another delimiter such as a comma or tab?

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is you can represent each row as a string, i.e. mapping the 2D array into an 1D array. Then, all you need to do is unpack and repack the row's string whenever you make an edit:

```bash
# Init a 4x5 matrix
a=("00 01 02 03 04" "10 11 12 13 14" "20 21 22 23 24" "30 31 32 33 34")

aset() {
  row=$1
  col=$2
  value=$3
  IFS=' ' read -r -a rowdata <<< "${a[$row]}"
  rowdata[$col]=$value
  a[$row]="${rowdata[@]}"
}

aget() {
  row=$1
  col=$2
  IFS=' ' read -r -a rowdata <<< "${a[$row]}"
  echo ${rowdata[$col]}
}

aprint() {
  for rowdata in "${a[@]}"; do
    echo $rowdata
  done
}

echo "Matrix before change"
aprint

# Outputs: a[2][3] == 23
echo "a[2][3] == $( aget 2 3 )"

echo "a[2][3] = 9999"
aset 2 3 9999

# Show result
echo "Matrix after change"
aprint
```

Outputs:

```bash
Matrix before change
00 01 02 03 04
10 11 12 13 14
20 21 22 23 24
30 31 32 33 34
a[2][3] == 23
a[2][3] = 9999
Matrix after change
00 01 02 03 04
10 11 12 13 14
20 21 22 9999 24
30 31 32 33 34
```

Comment: and how to easily unpack a row into multiple values?

Comment: @noisy `IFS=' ' read -r -a tmp <<< "${a[$row]}"` unpacks a row into multiple values.

Answer (score 7):

2D array can be achieved in bash by declaring 1D array and then elements can be accessed using `(r * col_size) + c)`. Below logic delcares 1D array (`str_2d_arr`) and prints as 2D array.

```
col_size=3
str_2d_arr=()
str_2d_arr+=('abc' '200' 'xyz')
str_2d_arr+=('def' '300' 'ccc')
str_2d_arr+=('aaa' '400' 'ddd')

echo "Print 2D array"
col_count=0
for elem in ${str_2d_arr[@]}; do
    if [ ${col_count} -eq ${col_size} ]; then
        echo ""
        col_count=0
    fi
    echo -e "$elem \c"
    ((col_count++))
done
echo ""
```

Output is

```
Print 2D array
abc 200 xyz 
def 300 ccc
aaa 400 ddd
```

Below logic is very useful to get each row from the above declared 1D array `str_2d_arr`.

```
# Get nth row and update to 2nd arg
get_row_n()
{
    row=$1
    local -n a=$2
    start_idx=$((row * col_size))
    for ((i = 0; i < ${col_size}; i++)); do
        idx=$((start_idx + i))
        a+=(${str_2d_arr[${idx}]})
    done
}

arr=()
get_row_n 0 arr
echo "Row 0"
for e in ${arr[@]}; do
    echo -e "$e \c"
done
echo ""
```

Output is

```
Row 0
abc 200 xyz
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also approach this in a much less smarter fashion

```
q=()
q+=( 1-2 )
q+=( a-b )

for set in ${q[@]};
do
echo ${set%%-*}
echo ${set##*-}
done
```

of course a 22 line solution or indirection is probably the better way to go and why not sprinkle eval every where to .

Comment: Where does the 22 line solution use indirection? For your solution, what are you going to do when writing a script that requires i/o and a user wants to input a `-` into the 'array'. Also if you want to simulate an array probably makes more sense to `echo ${set//-/ }` instead of your two.

Comment: That was my mistake i missed an or . I think that ${set//-/} is probably a better way to go ( I don`t know about the portability issues of %% and ## though I believe you ) . What if is a very dangerous question , if you ask it to many times you'll find you need A.I. for your option parser :{p

Comment: I don't understand how that is relevant or helps answer the question.

    ${set//-/ } would eliminate the '-', merging the values together. i.e., the echo results in 'ab' whereas the original code returns either 'a' or 'b' depending on which side of the '-' you want.

Answer (score 4):

A way to simulate arrays in bash (it can be adapted for any number of dimensions of an array):

```
#!/bin/bash

## The following functions implement vectors (arrays) operations in bash:
## Definition of a vector <v>:
##      v_0 - variable that stores the number of elements of the vector
##      v_1..v_n, where n=v_0 - variables that store the values of the vector elements

VectorAddElementNext () {
# Vector Add Element Next
# Adds the string contained in variable $2 in the next element position (vector length + 1) in vector $1

    local elem_value
    local vector_length
    local elem_name

    eval elem_value=\"\$$2\"
    eval vector_length=\$$1\_0
    if [ -z "$vector_length" ]; then
        vector_length=$((0))
    fi

    vector_length=$(( vector_length + 1 ))
    elem_name=$1_$vector_length

    eval $elem_name=\"\$elem_value\"
    eval $1_0=$vector_length
}

VectorAddElementDVNext () {
# Vector Add Element Direct Value Next
# Adds the string $2 in the next element position (vector length + 1) in vector $1

    local elem_value
    local vector_length
    local elem_name

    eval elem_value="$2"
    eval vector_length=\$$1\_0
    if [ -z "$vector_length" ]; then
        vector_length=$((0))
    fi

    vector_length=$(( vector_length + 1 ))
    elem_name=$1_$vector_length

    eval $elem_name=\"\$elem_value\"
    eval $1_0=$vector_length
}

VectorAddElement () {
# Vector Add Element
# Adds the string contained in the variable $3 in the position contained in $2 (variable or direct value) in the vector $1

    local elem_value
    local elem_position
    local vector_length
    local elem_name

    eval elem_value=\"\$$3\"
    elem_position=$(($2))
    eval vector_length=\$$1\_0
    if [ -z "$vector_length" ]; then
        vector_length=$((0))
    fi

    if [ $elem_position -ge $vector_length ]; then
        vector_length=$elem_position
    fi

    elem_name=$1_$elem_position

    eval $elem_name=\"\$elem_value\"
    if [ ! $elem_position -eq 0 ]; then
        eval $1_0=$vector_length
    fi
}

VectorAddElementDV () {
# Vector Add Element
# Adds the string $3 in the position $2 (variable or direct value) in the vector $1

    local elem_value
    local elem_position
    local vector_length
    local elem_name

    eval elem_value="$3"
    elem_position=$(($2))
    eval vector_length=\$$1\_0
    if [ -z "$vector_length" ]; then
        vector_length=$((0))
    fi

    if [ $elem_position -ge $vector_length ]; then
        vector_length=$elem_position
    fi

    elem_name=$1_$elem_position

    eval $elem_name=\"\$elem_value\"
    if [ ! $elem_position -eq 0 ]; then
        eval $1_0=$vector_length
    fi
}

VectorPrint () {
# Vector Print
# Prints all the elements names and values of the vector $1 on separate lines

    local vector_length

    vector_length=$(($1_0))
    if [ "$vector_length" = "0" ]; then
        echo "Vector \"$1\" is empty!"
    else
        echo "Vector \"$1\":"
        for ((i=1; i<=$vector_length; i++)); do
            eval echo \"[$i]: \\\"\$$1\_$i\\\"\"
            ###OR: eval printf \'\%s\\\n\' \"[\$i]: \\\"\$$1\_$i\\\"\"
        done
    fi
}

VectorDestroy () {
# Vector Destroy
# Empties all the elements values of the vector $1

    local vector_length

    vector_length=$(($1_0))
    if [ ! "$vector_length" = "0" ]; then
        for ((i=1; i<=$vector_length; i++)); do
            unset $1_$i
        done
        unset $1_0
    fi
}

##################
### MAIN START ###
##################

## Setting vector 'params' with all the parameters received by the script:
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    eval param="\${$i}"
    VectorAddElementNext params param
done

# Printing the vector 'params':
VectorPrint params

read temp

## Setting vector 'params2' with the elements of the vector 'params' in reversed order:
if [ -n "$params_0" ]; then
    for ((i=1; i<=$params_0; i++)); do
        count=$((params_0-i+1))
        VectorAddElement params2 count params_$i
    done
fi

# Printing the vector 'params2':
VectorPrint params2

read temp

## Getting the values of 'params2'`s elements and printing them:
if [ -n "$params2_0" ]; then
    echo "Printing the elements of the vector 'params2':"
    for ((i=1; i<=$params2_0; i++)); do
        eval current_elem_value=\"\$params2\_$i\"
        echo "params2_$i=\"$current_elem_value\""
    done
else
    echo "Vector 'params2' is empty!"
fi

read temp

## Creating a two dimensional array ('a'):
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    VectorAddElement a 0 i
    for ((j=1; j<=8; j++)); do
        value=$(( 8 * ( i - 1 ) + j ))
        VectorAddElementDV a_$i $j $value
    done
done

## Manually printing the two dimensional array ('a'):
echo "Printing the two-dimensional array 'a':"
if [ -n "$a_0" ]; then
    for ((i=1; i<=$a_0; i++)); do
        eval current_vector_lenght=\$a\_$i\_0
        if [ -n "$current_vector_lenght" ]; then
            for ((j=1; j<=$current_vector_lenght; j++)); do
                eval value=\"\$a\_$i\_$j\"
                printf "$value "
            done
        fi
        printf "\n"
    done
fi

################
### MAIN END ###
################
```

Answer (score 4):

If each row of the matrix is the same size, then you can simply use a linear array and multiplication.

That is,

```
a=()
for (( i=0; i<4; ++i )); do
  for (( j=0; j<5; ++j )); do
     a[i*5+j]=0
  done
done
```

Then your `a[2][3] = 3` becomes

```
a[2*5+3] = 3
```

This approach might be worth turning into a set of functions, but since you can't pass arrays to or return arrays from functions, you would have to use pass-by-name and sometimes `eval`. So I tend to file multidimensional arrays under "things bash is simply Not Meant To Do".

Answer (score 1):

One can simply define two functions to write ($4 is the assigned value) and read a matrix with arbitrary name ($1) and indexes ($2 and $3) exploiting eval and indirect referencing.

```
#!/bin/bash

matrix_write () {
 eval $1"_"$2"_"$3=$4
 # aux=$1"_"$2"_"$3          # Alternative way
 # let $aux=$4               # ---
}

matrix_read () {
 aux=$1"_"$2"_"$3
 echo ${!aux}
}

for ((i=1;i<10;i=i+1)); do
 for ((j=1;j<10;j=j+1)); do 
  matrix_write a $i $j $[$i*10+$j]
 done
done

for ((i=1;i<10;i=i+1)); do
 for ((j=1;j<10;j=j+1)); do 
  echo "a_"$i"_"$j"="$(matrix_read a $i $j)
 done
done
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Reed suggested a very good solution for 2D arrays (matrix)! They always can be converted in a 1D array (vector). Although Bash doesn't have a native support for 2D arrays, it's not that hard to create a simple ADT around the mentioned principle.

Here is a barebone example with no argument checks, etc, just to keep the solution clear: the array's size is set as two first elements in the instance (documentation for the Bash module that implements a matrix ADT,   https://github.com/vorakl/bash-libs/blob/master/src.docs/content/pages/matrix.rst )

```
#!/bin/bash

matrix_init() {
    # matrix_init instance x y data ...

    declare -n self=$1                                                          
    declare -i width=$2 height=$3                                                
    shift 3;                                                                    

    self=(${width} ${height} "$@")                                               
}                                                                               

matrix_get() {                                                                  
    # matrix_get instance x y

    declare -n self=$1                                                          
    declare -i x=$2 y=$3                                                        
    declare -i width=${self[0]} height=${self[1]}                                

    echo "${self[2+y*width+x]}"                                                 
}                                                                               

matrix_set() {                                                                  
    # matrix_set instance x y data

    declare -n self=$1                                                          
    declare -i x=$2 y=$3                                                        
    declare data="$4"                                                           
    declare -i width=${self[0]} height=${self[1]}                                

    self[2+y*width+x]="${data}"                                                 
}                                                                               

matrix_destroy() {                                                                     
    # matrix_destroy instance

    declare -n self=$1                                                          
    unset self                                                                  
}

# my_matrix[3][2]=( (one, two, three), ("1 1" "2 2" "3 3") )
matrix_init my_matrix \                                                         
        3 2 \                                                               
        one two three \                                                     
        "1 1" "2 2" "3 3"

# print my_matrix[2][0]
matrix_get my_matrix 2 0

# print my_matrix[1][1]
matrix_get my_matrix 1 1

# my_matrix[1][1]="4 4 4"
matrix_set my_matrix 1 1 "4 4 4"                                                

# print my_matrix[1][1]
matrix_get my_matrix 1 1                                                        

# remove my_matrix
matrix_destroy my_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

For simulating a 2-dimensional array, I first load the first n-elements (the elements of the first column)

```
local pano_array=()  

i=0

for line in $(grep  "filename" "$file")
do 
  url=$(extract_url_from_xml $line)
  pano_array[i]="$url"
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

To add the second column, I define the size of the first column and calculate the values in an offset variable

```
array_len="${#pano_array[@]}"

i=0

while [[ $i -lt $array_len ]]
do
  url="${pano_array[$i]}"
  offset=$(($array_len+i)) 
  found_file=$(get_file $url)
  pano_array[$offset]=$found_file

  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will definitely work provided if you are working on a Mac you have bash version 4. Not only can you declare 0 but this is more of a universal approach to dynamically accepting values.

## 2D Array

```
declare -A arr
echo "Enter the row"
read r
echo "Enter the column"
read c
i=0
j=0
echo "Enter the elements"
while [ $i -lt $r ]
do
  j=0
  while [ $j -lt $c ]
  do
    echo $i $j
    read m
    arr[${i},${j}]=$m
    j=`expr $j + 1`
  done
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done

i=0
j=0
while [ $i -lt $r ]
do
  j=0
  while [ $j -lt $c ]
  do
    echo -n ${arr[${i},${j}]} " "
    j=`expr $j + 1`
  done
  echo ""
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```