# Bash Arrays - Couldn't extract the assigned variable from the array(2D)

Tags: arrays, bash, multidimensional-array

I used the array assignment below in order to simulate a two dimensional array:

```
for((i=0;i<2;i++))        
do        
    for((j=0;j<3;j++))        
    do        
        read TWOD$i[$j]        
    done        
done < hi.txt
```

The file `hi.txt` contains these lines:

```
 1    
 2    
 3    
 4     
 5    
 6
```

If I use `echo ${TWOD0[2]}`, I can print the value 2, but if I am using a variable for the first index, bash throws a syntax error `bad substitution`:

```
 for((i=0;i<2;i++))    
 do    
     printf "%s\n" "${TWOD$i[2]}"    
 done
```

Is there any way to extract the elements from the array using a variable for the first index?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indirect expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/bash-indirect-expansion-please-explain):

```
row="TWOD$i[2]"
printf "%s\n" ${!row}
```