# How to create a dynamic variable and assign value to it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a dynamic variable and assign `100` to it

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.   
active_id=$p_val 
flag_$active_id=100
```

But I am getting error in doing so, any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash dynamic variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use **bash's declare directive and indirection feature** like this:

```
p_val="foo"
active_id=$p_val
declare "flag_$active_id"="100"
```

**TESTING:**

```
> set | grep flag
flag_foo=100
```

**UPDATE:**

```
p_val="foo"
active_id="$p_val"
v="flag_$active_id"
declare "$v"="100"

> echo "$v"
flag_foo
> echo "${!v}"
100
```

**Usage in `if condition`:**

```
if [ "${!v}" -ne 100 ]; then
   echo "yes"
else
   echo "no"
fi

# prints no
```

Comment: thanks anubhava, but i am getting error in this code:
if [ flag_$active_id -ne 100 ]
then ... else ...

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal: Check my **Update** section, I have provided an example of its use in `if then ... else ... fi` block.

Comment: what is the significance of semicolon here "if [ "${!v}" -ne 100 ];"

Comment: `"${!v}"` is called indirection which means the real variable name is contained in `$v` (`flag_foo`)

Comment: this does not work for assigning an array. solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16487405/3779853

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what this should be good for but you can achieve stuff like this with bash's `eval` statement.

The following code illustrates that.

```
#!/bin/bash

p_val="TEST"
active_id=$p_val 

eval "flag_$active_id=100"

echo $flag_TEST
eval "echo \$flag_$active_id"
```

The terminating `echo`'s puts

```
100
100
```

on the `stdout`.

Comment: Just a friendly word of warning, while this will work, eval is a super dangerous, specially on the shell. so never use in anything that comes from user input. ever.