# Basic bash Bucle for "Command not Found"

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/sh
INF_PROC=`ps -l`
for (( i=1; i<5; i++ ))
do
    id$i=$(echo $INF_PROC | cut -d ' ' -f $i)
    echo $id$i
done
```

Im learning bash and trying to use a for similar to this but it gives me an error. "Command not found" 
Why is that?

Comment: if you're learning bash, be sure to use `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your scripts. Using `#!/bin/sh` imposes significant restrictions on what features you can use. AND use the `{}` tool from the Format Menu on mouse-selected text to format correctly as `code/data/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is `id$i=...`. Someone link this as a duplicate.

Comment: AND check you code before posting at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the tips, the /sh may be because im using xcode on mac. I didn't know how to format the menu, thanks again

Comment: I agree with @Socowi . Read this post to understand your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018808/how-to-create-a-dynamic-variable-and-assign-value-to-it?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Good luck.

Comment: It looks like an array would be a much cleaner solution than a dynamic variable name. Just use `id[i]=...` and `echo "${id[i]}"`. (I'm sure there's already a q/a that covers this, but I can't find it at the moment).

Comment: I've added a couple of duplicates with answers that cover using arrays for situations like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that's exactly what i needed, thanks

Comment: I've found it works without indent the text, so command must be starting same as 'do'

Answer (score -2):

The **shebang** `#!/bin/sh` is the deciding factor on which shell executes your script.

Since the script is using bash-specific features, namely `(( i=1; i<5; i++ ))`, the shebang should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Alternatively you can rewrite the script in such a way that it only uses elements that can be interpreted by all POSIX-compliant shells, such as `sh`.

You can do this by writing your loop like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
INF_PROC=`ps -l`
for i in $(seq 5)
do
    id$i=$(echo $INF_PROC | cut -d ' ' -f $i)
    echo $id$i
done
```

Comment: it gives me the same error: pruebainfocomando.sh: line 7: id1=UID: command not found
1
pruebainfocomando.sh: line 7: id2=PID: command not found
2
pruebainfocomando.sh: line 7: id3=PPID: command not found
3
pruebainfocomando.sh: line 7: id4=F: command not found
4 
pruebainfocomando.sh: line 7: id5=CPU: command not found
5

Comment: try `echo $INF_PROC | cut -d ' ' -f $i | read id$i` instead of `id$i=$(echo $INF_PROC | cut -d ' ' -f $i)`.

Comment: Now it returns 1 2 3 4 5, but i need the words UID, PID, PPID,CPU

Comment: `Read` in a pipeline will not work because the commands in pipelines run in a subshell. Use `declare variable=value` with subshells `$()` instead. But even better: Don't answer this question which was answered multiple times. Search for duplicates and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @socowi How would you edit the code? I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: @juri_d You've completely ignored the real problem, which is the assignment to `id$i`.