# it can only print the first and last value when using for loop to read an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

There are some rotate gz log file in the log dir,it rotaes every **twenty** minutes using logrotate with dateformat '.%s'， as flows

```
ls -l /var/log/app/h323server.log.[1-9][0-9]*  |head
-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm   2063852 Mar 19 02:00 /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584554401.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm   2093937 Mar 19 02:20 /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584555601.gz
```

I want to print the corresponding **log content** between start_time timestamp and end_time timestamp，there are a few steps:

1, find out the log file and fill them into an array named totalfile

2, use for loop to read totalfile and print, the **first** and **last** element need to filter by start and end timestamp, print the rest of file direcly. I want to use `for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}+1; i++ ));`
 loop to achieve it，but something goes wrong.

The Bash script is as fllow:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
declare -a filetime
declare -a filename
declare -a totalfile
index_1=0
index_2=0

for line in $(ls -l /var/log/app/h323server.log.[1-9][0-9]* |awk '{split($NF,a,".");print a[3],$NF}')
do
        filetime[${index_1}]=$(echo ${line} |awk '{print $1}')
        filename[${index_2}]=$(echo ${line} |awk '{print $2}')
        ((index_1++))
        ((index_2++))
done
IFS="$oldifs" 

index=0
timesys_s=1584945601
timesys_e=1584948001

# store the corresponding delaycompress and compress file to totalfile array
while [ ${index} -le $((${#filetime[@]}-1)) ]
do
        if [ ${index} -eq 0 ]
        then
                if [[ ${filetime[${index}]} -ge ${timesys_s} ]] || \
                   [[ ${filetime[${index}]} -le ${timesys_s} ]] || \
                   [[ (${filetime[${index}-1]} -ge ${timesys_s}) && (${filetime[${index}]} -le ${timesys_e}) ]]
                then
                        totalfile[${index}]=${filename[${index}]}
                fi
        else
                if [[ (${filetime[${index}-1]} -le ${timesys_s}) && (${filetime[${index}]} -ge ${timesys_s}) ]] || \
                   [[ (${filetime[${index}-1]} -ge ${timesys_s}) && (${filetime[${index}]} -le ${timesys_e}) ]] || \
                   [[ (${filetime[${index}-1]} -le ${timesys_e}) && (${filetime[${index}]} -ge ${timesys_e}) ]]
                then
                        totalfile[${index}]=${filename[${index}]}
                fi
        fi
        ((index++))
done

echo "length of totalfile:"
echo ${#totalfile[@]}
echo "content of totalfile:"
echo ${totalfile[@]}

# get length of totalfile
arraylength=${#totalfile[@]}

# use for loop to read all values and indexes
for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}+1; i++ ));
do
  echo $i " / " ${arraylength} " : " ${totalfile[$i-1]}
done

# can only print the first and last value when using ${array[index]} to loop
echo "the length of totalfile is: ${arraylength}"
echo "the 1st element: ${totalfile[0]}"
echo "the 2st element: ${totalfile[1]}"
echo "the 3st element: ${totalfile[2]}"
echo "the 4st element: ${totalfile[3]}"
echo "the 5st element: ${totalfile[-1]}"
```

the output is as follows:

```
length of totalfile:
5
content of totalfile:
/var/log/app/h323server.log.1584554401.gz /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584945601.gz /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584946801.gz /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584948001.gz /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584949201.gz
1  /  5  :  /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584554401.gz
2  /  5  : 
3  /  5  : 
4  /  5  : 
5  /  5  : 
the length of totalfile is: 5
the 1st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584554401.gz
the 2st element: 
the 3st element: 
the 4st element: 
the 5st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584949201.gz
```

The question is:

There are five element in the totalfile array, but only "${totalfile[0]}" and "${totalfile[-1]}" can print normally, while "${totalfile[1]}","${totalfile[2]}" and "${totalfile[3]}" does not print at all.

One more thing, when I use "${totalfile[-4]}","${totalfile[-3]}" and "${totalfile[-2]}", it works.

use -4,-3,-2, instead of 1,2,3

```
echo "the length of totalfile is: ${arraylength}"
echo "the 1st element: ${totalfile[0]}"
echo "the 2st element: ${totalfile[-4]}"
echo "the 3st element: ${totalfile[-3]}"
echo "the 4st element: ${totalfile[-2]}"
echo "the 5st element: ${totalfile[-1]}"
```

output:

```
the length of totalfile is: 5
the 1st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584554401.gz
the 2st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584945601.gz
the 3st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584946801.gz
the 4st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584948001.gz
the 5st element: /var/log/app/h323server.log.1584949201.gz
```

The os system is "Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS".

I don't understand how it happens.And I'll be appreciated if anyone can explain it to me.

Comment: Run `declare -p totalfile` to see the contents of the array.

Comment: @codeforester let me try.

Comment: It does not work and the error is `line 7: declare: totalfile: not found` I cchanged '`declare -a totalfile` to `declare -a totalfile`

Comment: the index  value changed also,not 0-4, it turns to 0,326,237,328,329           declare -a totalfile='([0]="/var/log/app/h323server.log.1584554401.gz" [326]="/var/log/app/h323server.log.1584945601.gz" [327]="/var/log/app/h323server.log.1584946801.gz" [328]="/var/log/app/h323server.log.1584948001.gz" [329]="/var/log/app/h323server.log.1584949201.gz")'

Comment: Should it be `print a[2],$NF` ?

Comment: @Philippe the initial index is `1` of the array generated by `split`  in awk，you can try and see.

Comment: Can you run `declare -p totaltime` ?

Comment: @Philippe I have ran，it seems the index value is not correct, and i'm solving it.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script and debug it. [how we debug bash scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script). I don't understand the script  - what is going on in the `while [ ${index} -le $((${#filetime[@]}-1)) ]` loop?

Comment: @KamilCuk   the array of filetime stores the ` timestamp` of  all log files,while filename stores the `filename` of all log files. The index value of `filetime` and `filename` is same,and the `while [ ${index} -le $((${#filetime[@]}-1)) ]` loop  to find the log find between start_time and endtime

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your deleted answer and the advice.At the very beginning ,I use the way, in your answer，but when the number of gz file is big, `start_time < $2 && $2 < stop_time` will be executed by every gz file,it  will takes  many time,so I use the current way

Comment: @KamilCuk  oops,you add again, thanks

Comment: `,it will takes many time` - bash comparisons will be very, very slow. In `awk` it will be very fast. Each time you write `[` it runs a separate process, each process has it's own address space etc. Use `[[` or better `((` for a little bit speed. Or the best is to just run a single process, like `awk`.

Comment: @KamilCuk  The script is to print log content between start_time and end_time,there are some content of script that I don't post,which is to print log content using `zcat -f ${totalfile[index_value]}`, if `start_time < $2 && $2 < stop_time ` is executed,it turn out to be very slow,I have added `time` to test before. BTW,I have used `-x `,but it does not print the index of totalfile array,it shows when running `declare -p totalfile`,but I don't know before.Thanks again,all of you.

Comment: @Philippe I add a variable named `index_t` and set its value to `0`,then add ` ((index_t++))` in  the time comparison  'if' condition, `while [ ${index} -le $((${#filetime[@]}-1)) ] --> if [[ ${filetime[${index}]} -ge ${timesys_s} ]] and if [[ (${filetime[${index}-1]} -le ${timesys_s}) && (${filetime[${index}]} -ge ${timesys_s}) ]] `. it works now.

Comment: @KamilCuk Since awk can't print the content of `gz` file,so I have to use ·zcat· instead,but I don't want to compare time of every log file,only compare start_time and end_time of the fisrt and the last one,the rest  of gz file just use `zcat` to print the log content

Comment: No, it can't. So use `zcat` on resulting list. You _filter_ the file names with `awk`. _Then_ you print with `xargs zcat`. Unix philosophy is one tool does good one job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing state can be complicated in bash. Just parse the stream as it goes.

```
start_time='now -2 hour'
stop_time='now -1 hour'

# convert to seconds since epoch
start_time=$(date --date="$start_time" +%s)
stop_time=$(date --date="$stop_time" +%s)

# get list of files
( cd /var/log/app/ && find . -type f -name 'h323server.log.*.gz' ;) |
# extract the number
sed 's/\.\([0-9]*\).gz$/& \1/' |
# compare and print the filename
awk -v start_time="$start_time" -v stop_time="$stop_time" \
     'start_time < $2 && $2 < (stop_time + 20 * 60) { print $1 }' 
# I guess maybe also `(start_time - 20 * 60)` to fetch the previous one
```

Notes:

- Nice script!
- Use `for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i))` to iterate over array indexes. Or just `for i in ${!array[@]}`.
- I prefer arithmetic expansion, instead of `if [[ ${filetime[${index}]} -ge ${timesys_s} ]]` I would `if (( ${filetime[${index}]} >= ${timesys_s} ))`.

Or for example get the file before and after the match:

```
find . -type f -name 'h323server.log.*.gz' |
# extract the number
sed 's/\.\([0-9]*\).gz$/& \1/' |
# sort on numbers
sort -n -k2 |
# important - the input is sorted
# compare and print the filename 
awk -v start_time="$start_time" -v stop_time="$stop_time" '
    # Because i dont want to write  stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time everrywhere, I cache it in cond variable
    # clear cond variable
    { cond=0 }
    stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time {
        cond_was_true=1; # remember that at least once the condition was met
        cond=1; # if the condition is met, set cond variable
    }
    # so, if the condition is met
    cond {
        # output the previous line before the match if any
        # if we did not output the previous line yet (oncelast)
        # and the previous line length is not empty
        if (!oncelast && length(last) != 0) {
            # remember that we ouputted the previous line and output it
            oncelast=1
            print last;
        }
        # output the current line
        print $1;
        # there is nothing interesting below
        next;
    }
    # remember the previous line
    # the !cond could be just removed, it want be executed because next above
    !cond { last=$1; }
    # print one more line after the condition is true
    # if the condition was true before
    # but is no longer true
    # then only once output the next line after the condition was met
    cond_was_true && !cond && !once { once=1; print $1; }
'
```

If you seem to want to print the content of resulting files, add `| xargs -d$'\n' zcat` on the end of the scripts.

After the `sort -n -k2` the input is sorted using the timestamps. So we have a condition `stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time` and I am interested in the one line before and one after the range the condition is met for the input.

Above I used `cond` variable to just not write `stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time` over and over again. I guess I'll try to rewrite a simpler version, but untested:

awk -v start_time="$start_time" -v stop_time="$stop_time" '

```
    stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time {
        # if the condition wasnt true, output the previous line
        if (!cond_was_true &&
               # and the previous_line is not empty
               length(previous_line) != 0) {
            print last;
        }
        # remember that the condition was true
        cond_was_true = 1;
        # output the current line
        print $1;
    }

    # remember the previous line
    { previous_line = $1; }

    # if the condition was true
    # but is no longer met
    # output the next line
    # but output it only once
    cond_was_true && 
             !(stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time) &&
             !output_next_line_once { 
         output_next_line_once = 1;
         print $1;
    }
'
```

Comment: It won't need `20 * 60` when using array,which is available when the rotate time is not 20 mins.

Comment: what does `last` mean in the second way? when I ran this,it display the filename and timestamp number  on the first line,the rest of line print only the filename. ./h323server.log.1584974401.gz 1584974401
./h323server.log.1584975601.gz
./h323server.log.1584976801.gz
./h323server.log.1584978001.gz
./h323server.log.1584979201.gz

Comment: There was a bug, should have been `last=$1`. I understood you need one file and one file after the match. `last` is used to store the line right before the match.

Comment: Can you tell me how `!oncelast && length(last) != 0` and  `!cond { last=$1; }` work, I only understand the `stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time` pattern and action.

Comment: I'll added some comments. `!oncelast && length(last) != 0` - I use `oncelast` variable to check if the previous line was outputted already. If it was, then I don't want to output the previous line. If it wasn't, then set `oncelast` to true and output it. The `lenght(last) != 0` checks if the length of content of variable `last` is nonzero. In case there is no previous line before the condition is met, there is nothing to output. The `{last=$1;}` is used to remember the line before the condition was met. By "condition" I mean `stop_time > $2 && $2 > start_time`. The `!cond` could be removed...

Comment: Thank for your detailed explanation.` !cond { last=$1; }` is only to  remember the line before the condition was met,it can be removed, is right? `next;` is to terminal the currenct loop and go to next loop like `continue` in `C` programming language?

Comment: That's yes and yes.

Comment: once ` !cond { last=$1; }` be removed.it can't output the the previous line which is not empty,beacause the initial value of `last` is empty，` !cond { last=$1; }` is used to store  the previous line $1 to `last`,when `cond` is true and `oncelast` is not true,output the previous line before match,so ` !cond { last=$1; }` can't be removed.

Comment: I have tried,with ` !cond { last=$1; }` ,previous line can be outputed,while previous line cannot be outputed without it

Comment: I'm sorry. `!cond` can be remove,not  ` !cond { last=$1; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should use readarray instead of a for loop to read the values:
[How to use 'readarray' in bash to read lines from a file into a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634978/how-to-use-readarray-in-bash-to-read-lines-from-a-file-into-a-2d-array)

But if you just want to get the first and last lines, sed is likely a good option instead:

```
$ sed -n -e '1p' -e '$p' /etc/passwd
below cmd output started 2020 Mon Mar 23 08:19:32 AM PDT
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
apacheds:x:124:131::/var/lib/apacheds:/bin/bash
```

BTW, what do you require for a log file with only one line in it?  Should it print the same line twice?

Comment: I want to loop all log file,here are 5 log file,but the question is 2st,3st,4st does not print when using `for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}+1; i++ ));`. the first and last element need to filter by start and end timestamp, while the rest of files print direcly.