# How to loop through a list of arrays, created in the bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I am creating a list of arrays in a bash script, per the suggestion in this post-
[How to declare 2D array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash) (Edit 2 by Sir Athos)-

---

Edit 2: To declare and initialize a0..a3[0..4] to 0, you could run:

```
for i in {0..3}; do
    eval "declare -a a$i=( $(for j in {0..4}; do echo 0; done) )"
done
```

---

Now I am having difficulty accessing the newly created arrays.  I am trying to loop through and recreate the array name the same as they were created, but resulting in 'bad substitution' error.

```
for j in {0..3}; do
    echo ${a$j[@]:0}
done
```

error received:

```
${a$i[@]:0}: bad substitution
```

Any thoughts on how to access the arrays?  Ultimately the list of arrays will be much larger and created dynamically.  This is simply an example

Comment: Which version of bash? 4.3 provides namevars, a far more powerful construct for indirect reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The approach you are using is bad. Use [jm666's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16487733/1899640) from the same question instead.**

With that out of the way:

```
a1=("foo" "bar")
a2=("baz" "etc")

j=1
var="a$j[@]"
echo "The value of $var is:" "${!var}"

i=0;
var2="a$j[$i]"
echo "The value of $var2 is ${!var2}"
```

will print

```
The value of a1[@] is: foo bar
The value of a1[0] is: foo
```

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed answer the request.  I missed the need for indirect variable references.  Also I switched to the answer from @jm666 as you noted since it truly makes more sense.