# two dimension array bash

Tags: arrays, dimension

I saw lots of article on this. The most useful for me was this one

[How to declare 2D array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash)

the answer seems really useful since he got 20 likes.
However I can't see what I do different (except my array isn't set in a loop)

```
matrix[0,0]=2
matrix[0,1]=1
matrix[1,0]=9
matrix[1,1]=8
matrix[1,2]=7

echo ${matrix[0,0]}
echo ${matrix[0,1]}
echo ${matrix[1,0]}
echo ${matrix[1,1]}
echo ${matrix[1,2]}
```

I get
9
8
9
8
7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the variable declaration as an *associative array* via `-A`:

```
typeset -A matrix
```

Without that, you seem to get a normal array, and then only the last index is actually used; that explains the (wrong) results you've got.

Comment: thx a lot! I saw it but I was convinced it was wrong... dunno why actually