# How to get the size of the second dimension of two dimensional arrays in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I have

```
arr[0,0]=0;
arr[0,1]=1;
```

And I try

```
echo ${#arr[0,@]}
```

I got

```
bash: 0,@: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "@")
```

What is the correct way to get the size of the second dimension or `arr`?

Comment: Not string keys; the index is evaluated in an arithmetic context, in which the comma operator is supported

Comment: Given the error this is arithmetic context. Without that this could be an associative array in which case anubhava would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported in BASH.
Nevertheless, you could simulate them using various [techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash).

The following definitions are the same:

- `arr[1,10]=anything`
- `arr["1,10"]=anything`

Both are evaluated to `arr[10]=anything` *(thanks [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner))*:

```
echo ${arr[10]}
anything
```

Comment: Then why is it legit to define `arr[0,0]=0`?

Comment: Because `0,0` is a legitimate arithmetic expression that evaluates to 0. (The comma operator returns the value of the second expression.)

Comment: @OneZero And for associative arrays it means string key `"0,0"`.

Comment: While I recognize there are ways to simulate them, how do I deal with the size problem then? If `0,0` is interpreted as a whole string, does it mean there's no way I can get the size of a second dimension?

Comment: @OneZero If you are using string indices to simulate them? Correct, you can't do it without counting (though that could be as simple as key expansion and parameter expansion I think).

Comment: @OneZero: If I needed 2d arrays, I would switch from bash to a language that supports them natively.

Comment: @chepner: your precious note put in the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't have multi-dimensional array. What you are trying to do, won't even simulate a multi-dimensional array unless you have declared the `arr` variable as an associative array. Check out the following test:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr[0,0]=0
arr[0,1]=1
arr[1,0]=2
arr[1,1]=3
echo "${arr[0,0]} ${arr[0,1]}" # will print 2 3 not 0 1
unset arr
declare -A arr
arr[0,0]=0
arr[0,1]=1
arr[1,0]=2
arr[1,1]=3
echo "${arr[0,0]} ${arr[0,1]}" # will print 0 1
```

And you can only get the size as a whole with `${arr[@]}`