# How to define associative 2-dimension array in shell script?

Tags: arrays, shell

I need to define an array like this:

```
declare -A myary
myary[fruits]=(apple peach benana)
myary[objects]=(car window door)
```

and loop through it.

How can I do it in shell scripting?

Thank you.

Comment: This question has been asked before.  See [google](https://www.google.com/#q=bash+two-dimensional+array).  You'll find that bash does not support 2-D arrays natively but that there are work-arounds if you really need them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Bash does not support multidimensional arrays. However, you can use one-dimensional associative arrays, and there are workarounds found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash).