# Array arithmetic in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, math

I have number of arrays in bash, such as `arrKey[]`, `aarT[]`,`P[]` and I want to do an arithmetic operation with these arrays. As I checked, arrays are working perfectly but, the arithmetic to find array `P[]` is wrong. 
Can anyone help me with this, please?

```
    #The format is C[0] = (A[0,0]*B[0]) + (A[0,1]*B[1])
```

this is the code that I tried so far.

```
    P[0]= $(({arrKey[0,0]} * {arrT[0]} ))+ $(({arrKey[0,1]} * {arrT[1]})) ))
    echo ${P[0]}
```

Comment: Bash does not support multidimensional arrays. You can simulate it, like check this question for usage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your line of code:

```
P[0]= $(({arrKey[0,0]} * {arrT[0]} ))+ $(({arrKey[0,1]} * {arrT[1]})) ))
```

- There is an additional space after the `=`, erase it.

  ```
  P[0]=$(({arrKey[0,0]} * {arrT[0]} ))+ $(({arrKey[0,1]} * {arrT[1]})) ))
  ```
- It is incorrect to add two elements outside of an Arithmetic expansion.
  Remove the additional parentheses:

  ```
  P[0]=$(({arrKey[0,0]} * {arrT[0]} + {arrKey[0,1]} * {arrT[1]}))
  ```
- either use a `$` or remove the `{…}` from variables inside a `$(( … ))`:

  ```
  P[0]=$(( arrKey[0,0] * arrT[0] + arrKey[0,1] * arrT[1] ))
  ```
- Even if not strictly required, it is a good idea to quote your expansions:

  ```
  P[0]="$(( arrKey[0,0] * arrT[0] + arrKey[0,1] * arrT[1] ))"
  ```

Also, make sure that the arrKey has been declared as an associative array:

```
declare -A arrKey
```

To make sure the intended double index `0,0` works.