# override of a 2D array cells in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I tried the following 2D array set in bash:

```
$ a[0,0]=a0
$ a[1,0]=a1
$ echo ${a[0,0]}
a1
```

I expect to get `a0`, What I m missing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this but I think that `0,0` and `1,0` are being evaluated inside an arithmetic context, so you get the same result as `$((1,0))` and `$((0,0))` i.e. the first digit is evaluated and discarded, leaving you with `0` in both cases. I don't know where you got the idea that multi-dimensional arrays are supported in the first place though.

Comment: Bash **ONLY** provides one-dimensional indexed and associative array variables. Although there're some tricky ways to simulate multi-dimensional arrays, they are not a good solution. 
If you have the chance, you'd better move to other scripting languages such as Perl, Pyhton or even some versions of Ksh where multi-dimensional arrays are supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add

```
declare -A a
```

Comment: Declaring a variable '-a'  (array) doesn't provide multi-dimensional support. Bash ONLY supports one-dimensional arrays. Although there're some tricky ways to simulate multi-dimensional arrays, they are not a good solution.

Comment: @MarcM it works for me

Comment: @MOHAMED: this is not really a 2D array - it's just a hack which simulates 2D arrays using hashes - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16487733/253056) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has no support for multi-dimensional arrays, but you can simulate 2d arrays as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash)