# Bash 2D Associative Arrays - how to retrieve all elments of specific key

Tags: bash, key, associative-array

Please review the sample code setup for 3x3 2D associative Array matrix. and at the bottom I'm trying print all the elements from 2D bash associative array matrix... ***for e.g. all [args] keys***...  But I'm not getting <s>what I needed...</s> specific keys printed for e.g.: all [args] keys...

My bash version:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

**What am I missing?**

```
declare -A assocArr
echo "Intialize the Associative Array (assocArr):"
assocArr[0,pid]=12345; assocArr[0,args]='/path/to/app/args'; assocArr[0,uptime]='4-2:50:35'
assocArr[1,pid]=56789; assocArr[1,args]='/path/to/app/args'; assocArr[1,uptime]='1-2:50:42'
assocArr[2,pid]=54321; assocArr[2,args]='/path/to/app2/args'; assocArr[2,uptime]='3-2:30:23'

echo "print the Associative Array (assocArr) elements:"
echo "assocArr[0,pid] is ${assocArr[0,pid]} ; assocArr[0,args] is ${assocArr[0,args]} ; assocArr[0,uptime] is ${assocArr[0,uptime]}"
echo "assocArr[1,pid] is ${assocArr[1,pid]} ; assocArr[1,args] is ${assocArr[1,args]} ; assocArr[1,uptime] is ${assocArr[1,uptime]}"
echo "assocArr[2,pid] is ${assocArr[2,pid]} ; assocArr[2,args] is ${assocArr[2,args]} ; assocArr[2,uptime] is ${assocArr[2,uptime]}"


echo "random element printing"
echo "${assocArr[1,args]}"


echo "PRINT ALL ELEMENTS of a SPECIFIC [key] for e.g.: all [args]"
echo "{assocArr[@,args]} : 
       ${assocArr[@,args]}"

echo "{assocArr[@ args]} :
       ${assocArr[@ args]}"

echo "{assocArr[@][args]} :
       ${assocArr[@][args]}"
```

Comment: You're not saying what you get and what you think you should get.

Comment: Unless this is a new feature that for some reason I cannot find any info on, bash associative arrays are strictly 1-dimensional. You can have a key such as `0,pid`, but in this case it's a single key which is the string `"0,pid"`, not two separate keys `0` and `pid`. This is why it is recommended to quote keys when indexing associative arrays, e.g., `${array["$key"]}`

Comment: You can simulate 2D arrays in bash, but you basically have to roll your own methods for doing so (e.g., `eval "declare -A array${id}"`, etc). I've done this before just on a lark, but I found it to be cumbersome and error-prone, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: My ignorance I guess; I latched onto the bash 2D Array idea from this another SO thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31276568/2288573). 

I now understand that Bash doesn't have a 2D array... and will have to devise something of my own

Comment: @BenjaminW. just edited my question to improve it a bit... but I learnt already that Bash has no 2D Array feature... I ended up using simple associative arrays for each different values args, uptime etc; using PID as my key.