Trying to declare an array in bash with a changing variable as part of the name, like $i in a for loop
I am not a geek of bash programming and I'm trying to write a bash script which is able to calculate the maximum common number that divides a set of given positive integers passed to the script as positional parameters.
I want to obtain an array of divisors for each of the positional parameters.
Everyone of these arrays must have a different name.
I thought to put a changing variable inside the array name, but it is giving me error.
I paste the code here.
#!/bin/bash

for k in $@
do
App+=("$k")

done

#echo "${Div\[\*\]}" | sort -nr
sortedDiv=( $( printf "%s\\n" "${App\[@\]}" | sort -n ) )
echo -e "\\n"
echo "${sortedDiv\[\*\]}"
echo -e "\\n"
a="${sortedDiv\[-2\]}"
declare -a Div\_

for i in $@
do

    div=1
    while true
    do
    
                if [ $(( $i % $div )) -eq 0 ]
                then
                      Div[j]_$i+=($div)
                      div=$(( $div + 1 ))
                      if [ $div -gt $a ]
                      then
                            break
                      fi
                 else
                      div=$(( $div + 1 ))
                      if [ $div -gt $a ]
                      then
                            break
                      fi
    
                 fi
    done

done

echo -e "\\n"
echo "${Div\[\*\]}"
echo  '${Div\_$i\[j\]} is worth "${Div\_$i\[\*\]}"'

When I execute this code I'm getting the following error:
./provaseria.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `$div' ./provaseria.sh: line 34: `Div\[j\]\_$i+=($div)'

Can someone please give me a hint about the way I can achieve my goal, that is obtain different arrays for each of the integers passed as positional parameters, where the elements of these arrays are the divisors of each positional parameter. Also I would like that these arrays to have names as Div_34 for example where 34 would be one of the positional parameters.
What I tried is the code I've just posted.
I hope that there is a way to obtain my goal
I want to get a result such as: ./scriptname.sh 34 89 65 78 270 198
And a response like this:
Div_34=(divisors of 34 )
Div_89=(divisors of 89)
Div_65=(divisors of 65)

And so on.......
I run the above code in Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64 bit
For example if I do the same thing for a variable it is working:
#!/bin/bash


var_=1

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    declare var_$i=$(( $var_ + $i ))
    echo "\$var_$i=$(( $var_ + $i ))"  

done

Why is it not possible to do the same thing for arrays ?

"${App\[@\]}", etc, look wrong.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash/31276568

Use $@ always with quotes: "$@". Otherwise it acts like $*.

Thanks to jhnc and Wimm for their suggestions

You don't need to calculate the divisors of the parameters in order to calculate the greatest common divisor (GCD).  Use the Euclidean algorithm.  This Bash code (with no error checking for missing parameters or parameters that are not positive integers) demonstrates one way to do it: gcd=$1; for n in "${@:2}"; do while r=$((n%gcd)); ((r!=0)); do n=$gcd; gcd=$r; done; done; printf '%d\n' "$gcd"

Thank you very much pjh for your suggestion. I will take it. Kind regards
