# Iterate over lists embedded as values in key/value pairs in bash

Tags: bash, dictionary

I'm trying to get a (key,multiple-value) structure (some sort of hashmap) in bash, like this :

```
[   
  [ "abc" : 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ "def" : "w", 33, 2 ]    
]
```

I'd like to iterate through eack key (some kind of `for key in ...`, and get each value with something like `map["def",2]` or  `map[$key,2]`.

I've seen a couple of threads talking about single-value hashmap, but nothing about this issue.

I could go with `N` arrays, `N` being the amount of key in my map, filled with every field in a row, but I don't want to duplicate code as much as possible.

Thanks in advance !

Edit : 
I'd like to go through the structure with something like this :

```
for key in ${map[@]} do;
  echo $key # "abc" then "def"
  for value in ${map[$key,@]} do;
    ...
  done
done
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want/need to use bash for this? It really isn't suited for this very well.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I really need bash on this one :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [multi-dimensional arrays in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash)

Comment: Well, it's not that elegant (I didn't expected the solution to be though).
I'll try it !

Comment: Which version of bash? If this is 4.3 or later, namevars are available, which make the many-arrays implementation far more tractable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using modern bash features with the multiple-array case:

---

Assignment (manual):

```
map_abc=( 1 2 3 4 )
map_def=( w 33 2 )
```

Assignment (programmatic):

```
append() {
  local array_name="${1}_$2"; shift; shift
  declare -g -a "$array_name"
  declare -n array="$array_name" # BASH 4.3 FEATURE
  array+=( "$@" )
}
append map abc 1 2 3 4
append map def w 33 2
```

Iteration (done inside a function to contain the namevar's scope):

```
iter() {
  for array in ${!map_@}; do
    echo "Iterating over array ${array#map_}"
    declare -n cur_array="$array" # BASH 4.3 FEATURE
    for key in "${!cur_array[@]}"; do
      echo "$key: ${cur_array[$key]}"
    done
  done
}
iter
```

---

This can also be done without namevars, but in an uglier and more error-prone fashion. (To be clear, I believe the code given here uses `eval` safely, but it's easy to get wrong -- if trying to build your own implementation on this template, please be very cautious).

```
# Compatible with older bash (should be through 3.x).
append() {
  local array_name="${1}_$2"; shift; shift
  declare -g -a "$array_name"

  local args_str cmd_str
  printf -v args_str '%q ' "$@"
  printf -v cmd_str "%q+=( %s )" "$array_name" "$args_str"
  eval "$cmd_str"
}
```

...and, to iterate in a way compatible with bash back through 3.x:

```
for array in ${!map_@}; do
  echo "Iterating over array ${array#map_}"

  printf -v cur_array_cmd 'cur_array=( ${%q[@]} )' "$array"
  eval "$cur_array_cmd"

  for key in "${!cur_array[@]}"; do
    echo "$key: ${cur_array[$key]}"
  done
done
```

This is more computationally efficient than filtering through a single large array (the other answer given) -- and, when namevars are available, arguably results in cleaner code as well.

Comment: Complete answer, beautiful post, and nice explanations. You deserve 1000 thanks !
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Do-able. The declaration is somewhat ugly

```
declare -A map=(
    [abc,0]=1
    [abc,1]=2
    [abc,2]=3
    [abc,3]=4
    [def,0]=w
    [def,1]=33
    [def,2]=2
)
key="def"
i=1
echo "${map[$key,$i]}"   # => 33
```

---

Iterating: helpful to keep a separate array of "keys":

```
keys=(abc def)
```

Then

```
for key in "${keys[@]}"; do 
    echo "$key"
    for idx in "${!map[@]}"; do 
        if [[ $idx == $key,* ]]; then 
            n=${idx##*,}
            printf "\t%s\t%s\n" "$n" "${map["$idx"]}"
        fi
    done
done
```

```
abc
    0   1
    1   2
    2   3
    3   4
def
    1   33
    0   w
    2   2
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit above ! 
Iterating through ${map[@]} (using a single loop) will output every value.

Comment: Updated. Unfortunately, complex bash data structures mean complex code