# "Push" onto bash associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I'm trying to run a script for all files in a directory with a common ID.

`ls -1 *.vcf`

```
a1.sourceA.vcf
a1.sourceB.vcf
a1.sourceC.vcf
a2.sourceA.vcf
a2.sourceB.vcf
a2.sourceC.vcf
a3.sourceA.vcf
a3.sourceC.vcf
```

The ID in each case precedes the first `.` (`a1`, `a2` or `a3`) and for each ID I want to have all the sources for that ID in an associative array, keyed by the ID, e.g.;

`a1` => [`a1.sourceA.vcf`, `a1.sourceB.vcf`, `a1.sourceC.vcf`]

I've attempted this as follows:

```
for file in $(ls *.vcf | sort)
do
  id=$(echo $file | cut -d '.' -f 1)
  vcfs[$id]+=$file

done

for i in "${!vcfs[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${vcfs[$i]}"
  echo " "
done
```

But I can't figure out how to get it working.

In Perl I would push values onto a hash of arrays in the loop:

`push @{$vcfs{$id}}, $file;`

to give me a data structure like this:

```
  'a1' => [
            'a1.sourceA.vcf',
            'a1.sourceB.vcf',
            'a1.sourceC.vcf'
          ],
  'a3' => [
            'a3.sourceA.vcf',
            'a3.sourceC.vcf'
          ],
  'a2' => [
            'a2.sourceA.vcf',
            'a2.sourceB.vcf',
            'a2.sourceC.vcf'
          ]
```

How can I achieve this in bash?

Comment: it stops with `a3` or you have `a4` and so?

Comment: @sjsam - any number of files

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28051297/1100158. That was the answer for a list of lists, but your solution will be similar.

Comment: @ccarton has an answer for you.  You can push to an associative array, but I'm not going to answer that, b/c you don't want to use an associative array (which has one value per key), but a hash array.  Bash doesn't support that, so you need the extensive work around that ccarton provided.

Answer (score 2):

From another answer given in question's comments

```
unset a1 a2 a3

function push {
    local arr_name=$1
    shift
    if [[ $(declare -p "$arr_name" 2>&1) != "declare -a "* ]]
    then
        declare -g -a "$arr_name"
    fi
    declare -n array=$arr_name
    array+=($@)
}

for file in *.vcf; do [[ -e $file ]] && push "${file%%.*}" "$file"; done

(IFS=,;echo "${a1[*]}")
(IFS=,;echo "${a2[*]}")
(IFS=,;echo "${a3[*]}")
```

But depending on needs maybe for with pattern is sufficient

```
for file in a1.*.vcf; do ... ; done
```

Finally `$(ls )` must not be used in `for` loops as seen in other answers.

[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)