# Bash - arrays in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to make a shell script but I'm stuck.

This doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
a=( "1" "2" )
b=( "3" "4" )
c=( "$a" "$b" )

for d in "${c[@]}"; do
    echo "${d[1]}"
done
```

Comment: In bash, array elements must be scalars, i.e., there's no multidimensional array in bash.

Comment: Do you know any way I can do something like this?

Comment: ksh93 has multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look.

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash
and this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
a=( "1" "2" )
b=( "3" "4" )

# concatenate array a and b to new array c
c=( "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}" )

for d in "${c[@]}"; do 
  echo "$d"
done
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```