# 2 Dimensional array in bash, cannot set value to a certain element in array

Tags: arrays, bash, 2d

I have a 2 dimensional array in bash and I am able to successfully initialize it, but when I choose to set a value to a certain element in the array- the script sets it to ALL the elements in the array ! Baffled ! I was hoping it would set to just that one element.

Here's the scenario - I have a 2 D array for all the 12 months in a year. ( let's say for year 2012. ) I am able to initialize it to '-1'. Later at some time in the code I want to set just the 6th month to say 1000, then the 'initializing' sets the 1000 to all the elements in the array. Why ?
I'm on a Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5 and running this as /bin/bash

```
declare -a outages

function init_array () {
    for (( month=1; month<12; month++)) do
        outages[$month,12]=-1
    done
    outages[6,12]=1000 # this is setting all elements to 1000, instead of just 1.
}
function print_array () {

    for ((i=1;i<=12;i++)) do
         echo  outages[$i,12] = ${outages[$i,12]}
    done

}
init_array
print_array

Results Cut and Pasted below.
./test.sh 
outages[1,12] = 1000
outages[2,12] = 1000
outages[3,12] = 1000
outages[4,12] = 1000
outages[5,12] = 1000
outages[6,12] = 1000
outages[7,12] = 1000
outages[8,12] = 1000
outages[9,12] = 1000
outages[10,12] = 1000
outages[11,12] = 1000
outages[12,12] = 1000
```

Comment: Always try debugging with a `set -x` option in cases like these. If you had run like that it will be obvious for you to understand that you were operating the array as a one-dimensional entity.

Comment: If you need a 2-dimensional array (or even nested arrays), you are using the wrong language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has two types of arrays:  one-dimensional indexed and associative array.  `declare -a` creates a one-dimensional array.  To mimic a 2-D array, you need an associative array.  Therefore, replace:

```
declare -a outages
```

with:

```
declare -A outages
```

With that one change:

```
$ bash test.sh
outages[1,12] = -1
outages[2,12] = -1
outages[3,12] = -1
outages[4,12] = -1
outages[5,12] = -1
outages[6,12] = 1000
outages[7,12] = -1
outages[8,12] = -1
outages[9,12] = -1
outages[10,12] = -1
outages[11,12] = -1
outages[12,12] =
```

(Note that `outages[12,12]` is never set because the loop is limited by `month<12`.)

#### What happens when you provide a 2-D subscript to a 1-D array

As in the original code, let's declare a 1-D array and try to use it as a 2-D array and see what happens:

```
$ declare -a outages
$ outages[1,2]=-1
```

This looks like it made a successful assignment to a 2-D array.  **But, that is not what happened.**  To see what really happened, use `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p outages
declare -a outages='([2]="-1")'
```

We can see that element `2` was assigned a value, not element `1,2`.  The reason is that subscripts of 1-D arrays are treated as *arithmetic expressions*.  Under the rules of arithmetic evaluation, [anything before a comma is discarded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

One can see this by looking directly at an arithmetic expression:

```
$ echo $((1,2))
2
```

Everything before the `,` is discarded.  That is why setting `outages[6,12]=1000` had the effect of setting all your other `,12` elements to 1000.

#### Documentation

From the section of `man bash` entitled "ARITHMETIC EVALUATION":

> The  operators  and  their  precedence, associativity,  and  values 
>   are the same as in the C language.

One needs to refer to C language documentation, such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), to find out what the comma operator actually does.

#### Simulating 2-D array with bash 3.x

There are some hacks to shoehorn 2-D-like features into bash 3.x's 1-D arrays.  See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash).  In this case, however, your subscripts are numeric and simpler approaches are possible.  Let's update the code like this:

```
$ cat test2.sh
declare -a outages

function init_array () {
    for (( month=1; month<=12; month++)) do
        outages[$month+100*12]=-1
    done
    outages[6+100*12]=1000 # this is setting all elements to 1000, instead of just 1.
}
function print_array () {

    for ((i=1;i<=12;i++)) do
         echo  "outages[$i,12] = ${outages[$i+100*12]}"
    done

}
init_array
print_array
```

The code runs as you want:

```
$ bash test2.sh
outages[1,12] = -1
outages[2,12] = -1
outages[3,12] = -1
outages[4,12] = -1
outages[5,12] = -1
outages[6,12] = 1000
outages[7,12] = -1
outages[8,12] = -1
outages[9,12] = -1
outages[10,12] = -1
outages[11,12] = -1
outages[12,12] = -1
```

We can see what the array `outages` looks like to bash with `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p outages
declare -a outages='([1201]="-1" [1202]="-1" [1203]="-1" [1204]="-1" [1205]="-1" [1206]="1000" [1207]="-1" [1208]="-1" [1209]="-1" [1210]="-1" [1211]="-1" [1212]="-1")'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am running this on Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite and declare -A is not recognized.
    
./test.sh: line 2: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
outages[1,12] = 1000
 
   
            bash -version

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Oops.  Good point. As you correctly found,  Bash 3.2 does not have associative arrays.  They were added to [bash version 4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) which was released in 2009.

Comment: @ShashiKiran I just updated the answer with a workaround that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks John - I voted for your answers and thanks for the help. Much appreciated.