# Array arithmetic in a bash shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, integer-arithmetic

This is the code that I have wrote in bash. The array `arrKey` is taking the user input and it's working well when I check. but I want to assign the elements in `arrKey[]` into new array `K1[]`, then values are changing. For `arrKey[0,1]` and `arrKey[1,0]`, I want to assign minus value in order to find the determinant of matrix later.

This is the Code:

```
  declare -A arrKey

  for ((i=0; i<2; i++)) do
      for((j=0; j<2;j++)) do
           read -p "Enter the key [$i, $j] =  :  " num
           arrKey[$i,$j]=$num
      done
  done

  declare -a K1
  K1[0,0]="$((arrKey[1,1] ))"
  K1[0,1]="$((0 - arrKey[0,1] ))"
  K1[1,0]="$((0 - arrKey[1,0] ))"
  K1[1,1]="$((arrKey[0,0] ))"

  echo ${arrKey[0,0]}
  echo ${arrKey[0,1]}
  echo ${arrKey[1,0]}
  echo ${arrKey[1,1]}
  echo
  echo ${K1[0,0]}
  echo ${K1[0,1]}
  echo ${K1[1,0]}
  echo ${K1[1,1]}
```

When I run array `K1[]` values not as expected.

```
  Enter the key [0, 0] = : 1
  Enter the key [0, 1] = : 2
  Enter the key [1, 0] = : 3
  Enter the key [1, 1] = : 4

  1
  2
  3
  4

  -3
  1
  -3
  1
```

Expected Output:

```
  Enter the key [0, 0] = : 1
  Enter the key [0, 1] = : 2
  Enter the key [1, 0] = : 3
  Enter the key [1, 1] = : 4

  1
  2
  3
  4

  4
  -2
  -3
  1
```

Comment: You are declaring `K1` as a normal array not an associative array so the `0,0` assignments aren't doing what you expect they are. (Try using `declare -p arrKey K1` to print out the actual array values to see what I mean.)

Comment: `bash` doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash

Comment: Excellent early Question, with code (gasp), sample input and debugging output. Keep posting and Good luck!

Comment: Based on your recent questions, you're trying to do things in bash -- arrays and math -- that bash really isn't good at. You can fake it, but you're likely to keep running into weird syntax issues, limitations, etc. I'd really recommend a almost any other language for things like this.

Comment: thank you very much for your comments. Gordan Davisson, I have got an assignment to do hillcipher program in bash. that's why i'm struggling with bash script.