# Error in initializing two-dimensional array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

Here is the code I have question on

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a data81

for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))
do
    for ((j=1; j<=2; j++))
    do
        data81[$i, $j]=$i
        printf "%4s" ${data81[$i, $j]}
        printf "%4s\n" ${data81[1, 1]}
    done
    echo
done
```

The output is the following:

```
   1   1
   1   1

   2   2
   2   2

   3   3
   3   3
```

which is not what I wanted, because I used `printf "%4s\n" ${data81[1, 1]}`, so the second column should be the same.

Comment: There are no two-dimensional arrays in Bash.  The code you have does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You can simulate multi-dimensional array using associative arrays.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-dimensional arrays in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash)

Comment: The index is evaluated in an arithmetic context, where `$i, $j` evaluates to `$i`.

Comment: If you need to work with two-dimensional arrays, pick a different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
declare -a data81
```

To this :

```
declare -A data81
```

This does not create a multi-dimensional array, but rather an associative array.  The index is a string that acts as a key to a dictionary-type data structure.  Be careful how you build the index, it must have the exact same structure every time you access an element.

Comment: Fred: I changed -a to -A, but my Mac complained that ` line 3: declare: -A: invalid optiondeclare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`

Comment: MacOS Bash is stuck at an older version that did not support associative arrays..

Comment: I am not used to MacOS.  It is very likely you can compile a recent version (but I cannot tell you how to do it), as the reason Apple has not updated is due, I think, to not liking the licence under which Bash 4 is published, and not to a technical limitation.  Maybe there is a way to get it pre-compiled, I really do not know.

Comment: If you have HomeBrew, you can use this command: `brew install bash`

Comment: Its also easy to download the source and build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a data81

for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))
do
    for ((j=1; j<=2; j++))
    do
        data81[$i$j]=$i
        printf "%4s" ${data81[$i$j]}
        printf "%4s\n" ${data81[11]}
    done
    echo
done
```