# A way to prevent certain variables and strings being used in a 'For loop'

Tags: string, bash, for-loop, variables

I have to write a bash script that ignores specific strings in variables to prevent file mixups. I am very new to bash and I have no idea how to make a line of code that checks for illegal variable/string combinations.

For example the strings `marble` and `igneous_rocks` should never be used together in a for loop. This is the code that needs to be changed:

```
    #!/bin/bash

IGNEOUS_BLOCK=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
METAMORPHIC_BLOCK=(eclogite marble)
SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK=(argillite chalk jaspillite)
ROCK_TYPE=(igneous_rocks metamorphic_rocks sedimentary_rocks)

#Buttons
  for igneous_block in "${IGNEOUS_BLOCK[@]}" ; do
  for rock_type in "${ROCK_TYPE[@]}" ; do
      printf "{
    \"parent\": \"block/button\",
    \"textures\": {
        \"texture\": \"strata:blocks/"$rock_type"/"$igneous_block"\"
    }
}"> "${igneous_block}_button.json"
  done;
  done;
```

This is what it should do:

If the varible `ROCK_TYPE` uses the string `igneous_rocks` it should only pick strings inside `IGNEOUS_BLOCK` and not from `METAMORPHIC_BLOCK` and `SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK`

This is what I want all the variables work:

`ROCK_TYPE` cycles through the strings available.

```
ROCK_TYPE=(igneous_rocks metamorphic_rocks sedimentary_rocks)
```

`IGNEOUS_BLOCK` should only be allowed use the string `igneous_rocks`.

```
IGNEOUS_BLOCK=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
```

`METAMORPHIC_BLOCK` should only be allowed use the string `metamorphic_rocks`.

```
METAMORPHIC_BLOCK=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
```

`SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK` should only be allowed use the string `sedimentary_rocks`.

```
SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
```

What needs to change in my code to make it work like I want it to?

Comment: Two `for` and `do` but only one `done`? Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I changed the code to have two `done` instead of one and added a shebang at the top but I still end up with 'sedimentary_rocks` being used along side 'aa'. How do I fix that?

Comment: Keep going through ShellCheck. The shebang shouldn't be indented, and the double quotes are wrong. But that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Executing the code in bash seems to be completely fine. ShellCheck only recommends alternatives to write the code. The files do get generated like they should be but the order of strings that's being used inside the code is wrong. Also The double quotes can be used in multiple ways. I also figured out that you can incase most of the code inside either double or single quotes.

Comment: `igneous_rocks it should only pick strings inside IGNEOUS_BLOCK` Why can't you have all of them lowercase or all of them uppercase? What's the point of converting the case? `it should only pick strings` Please post the output you want to have as plain text. `should only be allowed` What does it mean when a variable "is allowed to use"? A variable `SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK` is a variable, not a function, it can't do something.

Comment: The variable `ROCK_TYPES` contains the strings `igneous_rocks`, `metamorphic_rocks` and `sedimentary_rocks` if for example `igneous_rocks` is picked it i want a way to make sure only the strings `aa`, `adakite` and `pahoehoe` can be picked from the variable `IGNEOUS_BLOCK`. So the output inside the code should be `"texture": "strata:blocks/igneous_rocks/aa"` and not `"texture": "strata:blocks/sedimentary_rocks/aa"` `sedimentary_rocks` is the wrong string and I do not want that to happen.

Comment: Yes, and I ask, why doesn't _the variables_ aren't named `igneous_rocks=(aa adakite pahoehoe)` but some random `IGNEOUS_BLOCK`? Why would you aim to convert `igneous_rocks` into `IGNEOUS_BLOCK`? Why not name the variable `igneous_rocks` in the first place?

Comment: @Quizer9O8 It will help if you post expected output. Also, no point in repeating the code (e.g., SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK should only ,,, SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK=(aa adakite pahoehoe)`, it does not help understanding the question

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generating your client data files with bash/shell, which will bite you back sooner or later, because it is not very portable and hard to maintain, as yet another framework and tools-set to add to your build environment;

You'd better implement data generators with dedicated Gradle tasks as documented by the Minecraft-Forge project here: https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.14.x/datagen/intro/

If you still really want to do this with bash. Your code can work if you use nameref variables to dynamically reference the corresponding rock types arrays:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref used
igneous_rocks=('aa' 'adakite' 'pahoehoe')
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref used
metamorphic_rocks=('eclogite' 'marble')
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref used
sedimentary_rocks=('argillite' 'chalk' 'jaspillite')
rock_types=('igneous_rocks' 'metamorphic_rocks' 'sedimentary_rocks')

#Buttons
declare -n rock_type
for rock_type in "${rock_types[@]}"; do
  for rock_name in "${rock_type[@]}"; do
    cat <<JSON >"${rock_name}_button.json"
{
  "parent": "block/button",
  "textures": {
    "texture": "strata:blocks/${!rock_type}/$rock_name"
  }
}
JSON
  done
done
```

Example of the generated `adakite_button.json`:

```
{
  "parent": "block/button",
  "textures": {
    "texture": "strata:blocks/igneous_rocks/adakite"
  }
}
```

Or using `jq` to build the JSON instead of here_document:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref used
igneous_rocks=('aa' 'adakite' 'pahoehoe')
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref used
metamorphic_rocks=('eclogite' 'marble')
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref used
sedimentary_rocks=('argillite' 'chalk' 'jaspillite')
rock_types=('igneous_rocks' 'metamorphic_rocks' 'sedimentary_rocks')

#Buttons
declare -n rock_type
for rock_type in "${rock_types[@]}"; do
  for rock_name in "${rock_type[@]}"; do
    jq -n --arg rocktype "${!rock_type}" --arg rockname "$rock_name" \
      '{"parent":"block/button","textures":{"texture":("strata:blocks/"+$rocktype+"/"+$rockname)}}' >"${rock_name}_button.json"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to have nested data, where `ROCK_TYPE` is an array of types, and each type has an array of subtypes.

In real programming languages, you can have nested data structures which would make this quite easy, but unfortunately Bash only has really [ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash) [solutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for emulating nested data.

Instead, you can use a [`case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) statement to define the blocks array to iterate over:

```
#!/bin/bash

rock_types=(igneous_rocks metamorphic_rocks sedimentary_rocks)

for rock_type in "${rock_types[@]}"; do
    case $rock_type in
    igneous_rocks)
        blocks=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
        ;;
    metamorphic_rocks)
        blocks=(eclogite marble)
        ;;
    sedimentary_rocks)
        blocks=(argillite chalk jaspillite)
        ;;
    esac
    for block in "${blocks[@]}"; do
        echo "$rock_type/$block"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
igneous_rocks/aa
igneous_rocks/adakite
igneous_rocks/pahoehoe
metamorphic_rocks/eclogite
metamorphic_rocks/marble
sedimentary_rocks/argillite
sedimentary_rocks/chalk
sedimentary_rocks/jaspillite
```

BTW, all-caps variable names should be reserved for environment variables like `PATH` and other special variables like `RANDOM`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- OP wants to cycle through all rock types listed in the **ROCK_TYPE** array
- each rock type and matching ***_BLOCK** array have matching names with a) the array name being all caps and b) the string `rocks` replaced with `BLOCK`

---

One relatively easy method would be to use a `case` statement to determine which ***_BLOCK* array to reference based on the current rock type.

A first pass to verify the idea:

```
for rtype in "${ROCK_TYPE[@]}"
do
    echo "+++++ rock type = ${rtype}"

    case "${rtype}" in
        igneous_rocks)          printf "%s\n" "${IGNEOUS_BLOCK[@]}"     ;;
        metamorphic_rocks)      printf "%s\n" "${METAMORPHIC_BLOCK[@]}" ;;
        sedimentary_rocks)      printf "%s\n" "${SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK[@]}" ;;
    esac
done
```

Which generates:

```
+++++ rock type = igneous_rocks
aa
adakite
pahoehoe
+++++ rock type = metamorphic_rocks
eclogite
marble
+++++ rock type = sedimentary_rocks
argillite
chalk
jaspillite
```

There are a few ways to modify this to allow for looping through the individual values in an associated ***_BLOCK** array, eg:

```
for rtype in "${ROCK_TYPE[@]}"
do
        bname=${rtype//rocks/block}        # OPs example could use this for the 'texture' field and json file name

        for btype in $(case "${rtype}" in
                        igneous_rocks)          echo "${IGNEOUS_BLOCK[@]}"     ;;
                        metamorphic_rocks)      echo "${METAMORPHIC_BLOCK[@]}" ;;
                        sedimentary_rocks)      echo "${SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK[@]}" ;;
                       esac)
        do
                echo ".${rtype}.${bname}.${btype}."
        done
done
```

Which generates:

```
.igneous_rocks.igneous_block.aa.
.igneous_rocks.igneous_block.adakite.
.igneous_rocks.igneous_block.pahoehoe.
.metamorphic_rocks.metamorphic_block.eclogite.
.metamorphic_rocks.metamorphic_block.marble.
.sedimentary_rocks.sedimentary_block.argillite.
.sedimentary_rocks.sedimentary_block.chalk.
.sedimentary_rocks.sedimentary_block.jaspillite.
```

NOTE: periods added as visual delimiters

---

Another idea would be to use a `nameref` (ie, the value of one variable is used as the name of another variable).

NOTE: I'm including this option since the example shows similarly named rock types and block names, which in turn makes a `nameref` solution relatively easy to implement.

Consider the following (simple) example:

```
$ unset x h
$ x=5 h=x
$ echo $x
5
$ echo $h
x
$ typeset -n h       # define nameref
$ echo $h
5
$ x=10
$ echo $h
10
```

Alternatively:

```
$ unset x h
$ x=5
$ typeset -n h=x     # define nameref
$ echo $x
5
$ echo $h
5
$ x=10
$ echo $h
10
```

One idea on using `nameref`s for the rock/block problem:

```
for rtype in "${ROCK_TYPE[@]}"
do
        bname=${rtype//rocks/block}                     # again, use this for the 'texture' field and json file name

        typeset -u -n currblock=${rtype//rocks/BLOCK}   # define nameref, convert to all uppercase and replace 'rocks' with 'BLOCK'

        for btype in "${currblock[@]}"                  # loop through nameref'd values
        do
                echo ".${rtype}.${bname}.${btype}."
        done
done
```

Which generates the same set of output as the `case` solution:

```
.igneous_rocks.igneous_block.aa.
.igneous_rocks.igneous_block.adakite.
.igneous_rocks.igneous_block.pahoehoe.
.metamorphic_rocks.metamorphic_block.eclogite.
.metamorphic_rocks.metamorphic_block.marble.
.sedimentary_rocks.sedimentary_block.argillite.
.sedimentary_rocks.sedimentary_block.chalk.
.sedimentary_rocks.sedimentary_block.jaspillite.
```

NOTE: again, periods added as visual delimiters

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
IGNEOUS_BLOCK=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
METAMORPHIC_BLOCK=(eclogite marble)
SEDIMENTARY_BLOCK=(argillite chalk jaspillite)
ROCK_TYPE=(igneous_rocks metamorphic_rocks sedimentary_rocks)
for i in "${ROCK_TYPE[@]}"; do
    # convert to upercase, replace rocks
    n="${i//_rocks/_BLOCK}"
    n="${n^^}[@]"
    # Using indirect expansion
    for j in "${!n}"; do
       echo "$i/$j"
    done
done
```

would output:

```
igneous_rocks/aa
igneous_rocks/adakite
igneous_rocks/pahoehoe
metamorphic_rocks/eclogite
metamorphic_rocks/marble
sedimentary_rocks/argillite
sedimentary_rocks/chalk
sedimentary_rocks/jaspillite
```

Notes: upper case variables are by convention used for exported variables like PWD LINES COLUMNS UID EID TERM LC_ALL COUNTRY HISTSIZE etc. Prefer using lower case variables in your scripts.

You could name variables same way as array elements, saving you from some code:

```
igneous_rocks=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
metamorphic_rocks=(eclogite marble)
sedimentary_rocks=(argillite chalk jaspillite)
rock_types=(igneous_rocks metamorphic_rocks sedimentary_rocks)
for i in "${rock_types[@]}"; do
    n="${i}[@]"
    for j in "${!n}"; do
       echo "$i/$j"
    done
done
```

As an alternative to *indirect expansion* there is also a *namereference*.

```
igneous_rocks=(aa adakite pahoehoe)
metamorphic_rocks=(eclogite marble)
sedimentary_rocks=(argillite chalk jaspillite)
rock_types=(igneous_rocks metamorphic_rocks sedimentary_rocks)
for i in "${rock_types[@]}"; do
    declare -n n="$i"
    for j in "${n[@]}"; do
       echo "$i/$j"
    done
done
```

Comment: I took a look at the code solution you posted and I applied this to create `.json` files quite effectively. I think this is the method I will use from now on.

Comment: I also suggest you use `jq` to compose your JSON rather than concatenate strings.

Comment: The First code works perfectly fine but I have one tiny problem. I changed all my variables from lowercase to uppercase letters and now nothing happens. I found out this code `n="${r//_rocks/_block}"` seems to be the problem. Only if I keep in the lower case letters `n="${r//_rocks/_BLOCK}"` including variable lowercase letters it seems to work. How can I use just uppercase letters without the script doing nothing?

Comment: Sorry, I do not think anything can save you from understanding what the code actually does. [shell paramater expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). If you changed it upper case, you have to change the values of `rock_types` to upper case to. Or you could upper-case-it with `${parameter^^pattern}` expansion. Other then that, please show the code.