# Bash - How to assign list to array member

Tags: arrays, bash, list, dictionary

In `bash`, I've an array with values:

```
declare -A my_array
my_array['key1']='value1'
my_array['key2']='value2'

echo "-----my_array-----"
echo key1: ${my_array['key1']}
echo key2: ${my_array['key2']}
```

what works well:

```
-----my_array----- 
key1: value1 
key2: value2
```

Although, I'd like to have for a key, a **list** of values.
I've tried something like:

```
my_array['key2']=('value2.1', 'value2.2')
```

this gives the error:

> my_array['key2']: **cannot assign list to array member**

What is the Syntax to add a list into an array element and then to access an index values for a key?

Comment: `bash` arrays/lists are one dimensional.

Comment: It's time to use a different language, one with actual support for data structures.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Lists in most languages are one-dimensional; the difference is that the values they store aren't restricted to strings, as in `bash`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-dimensional arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sub arrays in `bash`

No. Thechnically, *shell variables* are only intended to hold *strings*. But...

### Creating an array of arrays (even *associative*), under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

In this answer, I will use *disk free*'s output (`df -k`) to create an *associative array*, **indexed by *device***. As `tmpfs` pseudo device is used for
many differents behaviour, this *field* **have to** contain a ***list***.

#### 1. Simpliest way, using special delimiter.

Here I use `spaces` to delimit contents of fields as they are space delimited by command. Then I use *bell* special character (`\007`) to delimit sub arrays.

Here is a sample, using `df` output, sorting creating ***lists*** by device. As result, all *`tmpfs`* will be stored together:

```bash
declare -A dfVars='()'
{
    read _;
    while read -r dev _ use free _ mpnt ;do
        dfVars["${dev##*/}"]+="$use $((use+free)) $mpnt"$'\07'
    done
} < <(
    LANG=C df -lk
)
```

You could parse:

```bash
for dev in ${!dfVars[@]} ;do
    IFS=$'\a\n' read -d '' -ra fields <<<"${dfVars["$dev"]%$'\a'}"
    for line in "${fields[@]}";do
        read -r use tot mpnt <<<"$line"
        printf "%-20s %11d %11d  %s\n" $dev $use $tot $mpnt
    done
done
```

May output someting like:

```
tmpfs                          0      188928  /dev/shm
tmpfs                      19284      188928  /run
tmpfs                          4        5120  /run/lock
tmpfs                          0      188928  /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                          0       37784  /run/user/33
tmpfs                          0       37784  /run/user/1001
devtmpfs                       0      184596  /dev
mmcblk0p1                  23193       42136  /boot
root                   115253500   117652696  /
```

Everything are stored into `$dfVars`:

```bash
declare -p dfVars
```

```
declare -A dfVars=([tmpfs]=$'0 188928 /dev/shm\a19284 188928 /run\a4 5120 /run/l
ock\a0 188928 /sys/fs/cgroup\a0 37784 /run/user/33\a0 37784 /run/user/1001\a' [d
evtmpfs]=$'0 184596 /dev\a' [mmcblk0p1]=$'23193 42136 /boot\a' [root]=$'11529034
8 117652696 /\a' )
```

Note: The separator I entered `\07` is shown as `\a` in this output.

#### 2. Stronger: Using *`nameref`*  for indexing arrays:

With this method, you create independant variables, wich could be array, associative array or even strings...

```bash
uuvar() { printf -v "$1" %s%09d "$2" $((++uuVarCnt));}
declare -A dfVars='()'
{
     read _
     while read -r dev _ use free _ mpnt ;do
         uuvar vname _df_
         dfVars["${dev##*/}"]+=$vname' ' 
         read -a $vname <<<"$use $((use+free)) $mpnt"
         done
} < <(LANG=C df -lk)
```

To parse this:

```bash
for dev in ${!dfVars[@]} ;do
    for sub in ${dfVars["$dev"]};do
        declare -n subDf=$sub
        printf "%-20s %11d %11d  %s\n" "$dev" "${subDf[@]}"
    done
done
```

```
tmpfs                          0      188928  /dev/shm
tmpfs                      19284      188928  /run
tmpfs                          4        5120  /run/lock
tmpfs                          0      188928  /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                          0       37784  /run/user/33
tmpfs                          0       37784  /run/user/1001
devtmpfs                       0      184596  /dev
mmcblk0p1                  23193       42136  /boot
root                   115254628   117652696  /
```

Where `$dfVars` and *sub variables* look like:

```bash
declare -p dfVars ${!_df_*}
```

```
declare -A dfVars=([tmpfs]="_df_000000003 _df_000000004 _df_000000005 _df_000000
006 _df_000000008 _df_000000009 " [devtmpfs]="_df_000000002 " [mmcblk0p1]="_df_0
00000007 " [root]="_df_000000001 " )
declare -- uuVarCnt="9"
_df_000000001=([0]="115335328" [1]="117652696" [2]="/")
_df_000000002=([0]="0" [1]="184596" [2]="/dev")
_df_000000003=([0]="0" [1]="188928" [2]="/dev/shm")
_df_000000004=([0]="19284" [1]="188928" [2]="/run")
_df_000000005=([0]="4" [1]="5120" [2]="/run/lock")
_df_000000006=([0]="0" [1]="188928" [2]="/sys/fs/cgroup")
_df_000000007=([0]="23193" [1]="42136" [2]="/boot")
_df_000000008=([0]="0" [1]="37784" [2]="/run/user/33")
_df_000000009=([0]="0" [1]="37784" [2]="/run/user/1001")
```

#### 3. Same, but as *associative array* of *associative sub arrays*:

```bash
declare -A dfVars='()'
uuvar() { printf -v "$1" %s%09d "$2" $((++uuVarCnt));}
{
    read _
    while read -r dev _ use free _ mpnt ;do
        uuvar vname _df_
        dfVars["${dev##*/}"]+=$vname' '
        declare -A $vname
        printf -v $vname[used] %d $use
        printf -v $vname[total] %d $((use+free))
        printf -v $vname[mount\ point] %s "$mpnt"
    done
} < <(LANG=C df -lk)
for dev in ${!dfVars[@]} ;do
    for sub in ${dfVars["$dev"]} ;do
        declare -n subDf=$sub
        printf "%-20s %11d %11d  %s\n" "$dev" \
            "${subDf[used]}" "${subDf[total]}" "${subDf["mount point"]}"
    done
done
```

```
## < snip same output >
```

Then

```bash
declare -p dfVars ${!_df_*}
```

```
declare -A dfVars=([tmpfs]="_df_000000003 _df_000000004 _df_000000005 _df_000000
006 _df_000000008 _df_000000009 " [devtmpfs]="_df_000000002 " [mmcblk0p1]="_df_0
00000007 " [root]="_df_000000001 " )
declare -- uuVarCnt="9"
_df_000000001=([used]="115358360" [total]="117652696" ["mount point"]="/" )
_df_000000002=([used]="0" [total]="184596" ["mount point"]="/dev" )
_df_000000003=([used]="0" [total]="188928" ["mount point"]="/dev/shm" )
_df_000000004=([used]="19284" [total]="188928" ["mount point"]="/run" )
_df_000000005=([used]="4" [total]="5120" ["mount point"]="/run/lock" )
_df_000000006=([used]="0" [total]="188928" ["mount point"]="/sys/fs/cgroup" )
_df_000000007=([used]="23193" [total]="42136" ["mount point"]="/boot" )
_df_000000008=([used]="0" [total]="37784" ["mount point"]="/run/user/33" )
_df_000000009=([used]="0" [total]="37784" ["mount point"]="/run/user/1001" )
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround :D

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible directly but there is a way to do this via variable expansion, like this:

```
declare -A my_array
my_array['key1']='value1'
my_array['key2']='value2'

value1="true value1"
value2="true value2"
```

Check:

```
$ echo ${!my_array['key1']}
true value1

$ echo ${!my_array['key2']}
true value2
```

It's more complicated if value* is an array, but also possible:

```
...
value1=("true value1.1" "true value1.2")
value1=("true value2.1" "true value2.2")
index="${my_array['key1']}[0]"

$ echo "${!index}"
true value2.1
```

This could be wrapped in a function:

```
fun(){
    local index1=${!1}
    local index2="$index1[$2]"
    echo  "${!index2}"
}

$ fun "my_array['key2']" 1
true value2.2
```

But IMO you should accept the limitation and rethink the design or consider to use another language.