# Bash read file assign each line to variables

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

This is my file

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Following is my code

```
i=0;
while read line;do
   arry_$i="${line[@]}";
   i=$(($i+1));
done < file.txt
IFS=' ';eval "arr_00=($arr_0)"
IFS=' ';eval "arr_11=($arr_1)"
IFS=' ';eval "arr_22=($arr_2)"
```

Following is the output

```
arry_0=1 2 3: command not found
arry_1=4 5 6: command not found
arry_2=7 8 9: command not found
```

When I try to assign file each line to variable noticed an "command not found"

Thank you for suggestions

Comment: That isn't how you define or assign to arrays in bash unfortunately.  Maybe this would help.  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: Also, if you want to store a value with spaces in a variable in bash its a little tricky (most bash parsing is done with whitespace).  

`arry_"$i"="\"${line[@]}\""` might work  or just `arry_"$i"="\"$line\""`

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767

Comment: With these changes I am getting same error
```
 while read line;do    arry_"$i"="\"${line[@]}\"";    i=$(($i+1)); done < file.txt
arry_9="1 2 3": command not found
arry_10="4 5 6": command not found
arry_11="7 8 9": command not found
```

Comment: Now I have edited the question

Comment: When you write `${line[@]}`, you treat `line` as if it were an array. However, `line` is a scalar. This can't be right.

Comment: Furthermore in `arry_$i=....`, since you have a parameter expansion to the left of the equal sign (the `$i` part), the line is interpreted as a command execution, not as an assignment. Hence the error message _command not found_. Don't do any quoting or parameter expansion to the left of the equal sign in an assignment!

Comment: check your code (including `#!/bin/bash` as the first line) at https://shellcheck.net . Fix those issues and if that doesn't solve your problem, update your question with corrected code. Good luck.

Comment: please update the question with the expected results; do you want 3 variables where each variable is a string (eg, `arry_0='1 2 3'`) or should those 3 variables represent arrays (eg, `arry_0=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")` or are you expecting something else?

Comment: You can make the loop do what (I think) you want to do by replacing it with `while read -r -a "arry_$i"; do i=$((i+1)); done <file.txt` .  It's generally not a good idea to try to simulate multi-dimensional arrays in this way.  See [How to declare 2D array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16487258/4154375) and [Multi-dimensional arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11233825/4154375).

Comment: Use `readarray` instead of a loop to load the lines of a file into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just addressing the error message:

When you do:

```
   arry_$i="${line[@]}";
```

the shell does not recognise this as a variable assignment as it does not match the form `name=[value]` because `arry_$i` is not a valid form for a name.

After this it performs the various expansions, word-splitting, quote-removal, etc. On the first loop iteration, this results in a word `arry_0=1 2 3`.

This word is treated as a command to run. This gives your error message.

---

While strongly advising that you do not do the following, you could fix the problem by making the variable name generation happen before you attempt to assign to it:

```
while read line; do
   declare -n var=arry_$i
   var=$line;
   ((i++))
done < file.txt
```

Note that since `line` is a simple variable and not an array, `${line[@]}` == `${line[0]}` == `$line`.

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `exec` is.
For the sample data shown, it would be fine to directly execute: `arry_00=($arry_0)`, etc