# why my bash multidimensional array code is not working?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, multidimensional-array, element

i am trying to make a multidimaensional array in bash and access the elements. but its not working.

I tried with this code but there's error

```
# Create an indexed array to hold the inner arrays
    array=()

# Initialize the inner arrays
  array[0]=(1 2 3)
  array[1]=(4 5 6)
  array[2]=(7 8 9)

# Access elements
  element_12="${array[1][2]}"
  echo "Element at [1][2]: $element_12"

# Loop through the elements
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        inner_array=("${array[i][@]}")  # Copy the inner array
        for ((j = 0; j < ${#inner_array[@]}; j++)); do
            echo "Element at [$i][$j]: ${inner_array[j]}"
       done
   done
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message. It's hard to answer "why" in relation to "not working". Your code is "working", just not the way _you_ expect it to. It doesn't behave the way you expect it to, because it is supposed to behave in that way.

Comment: it throws the error message that you have mentioned later. 
is there any way to do it in bash?

Comment: bash does not have multidimensional arrays.  Why would you expect, that your code works?

Comment: Also see [How to declare 2D array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16487258/4154375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why my bash multidimensional array code is not working?

Because Bash does not support multidimensional arrays. In particular, Bash does not support assigning a list to an array member, which should be included in the error message:

```
$ array[0]=(1 2 3)                                                                                                                             
-bash: array[0]: cannot assign list to array member
```

Comment: any other ways to do it in bash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash