# Error in bash script - assign value to variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to make a small script that will give me the File names without the `$2` first and `$3` last names in a `$1` directory

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash
TOTFILES=find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} ';' | wc -l
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} ';' | sort |
    head -n (( TOTFILES-$3 )) | tail -n (( TOTFILES-$3-$2 ))
```

My main problem is that I can't assign TOTFILES with the output of that long line.

I think if I can get that value assigned, it will work 
(hopefully) :)

PS:
I don't know if I used

```
(( TOTFILES-$3 ))
```

right, to get the value.

Thanks for the fast answer.
Now I get a new problem; I guess `(( ))` is not the right way to get number

```
./middleFiles: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./middleFiles: line 5: `find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} ';' | sort | head -n (( TOTFILES-$3 ))  | tail -n (( TOTFILES-$3-$2 ))'
```

Comment: Note that the `exec basename` only slows things down unless you think directory names might contain newlines.  Otherwise, you could be just as accurate with `-print` instead of `-exec`.

Comment: thx, but speed is not really inportent for this task, just want it to do the right job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) assigns the output of a command:

```
TOTFILES=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} ';' | wc -l)
```

[Arithmetic expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) will get you the argument to `head` and `tail`:

```
head -n $(( $TOTFILES - $3 ))
```

Comment: exelent, but i have a follow up question ( i addd the question) i will be more then happy if you will be able to help me :)

Comment: I was still editing my answer when you posted your follow-up :-)

Comment: Dude, you really saved me, broke my head around, well thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need backticks around the expression you want evaluated.

```
TOTFILES=`find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} ';' | wc -l`
```

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash) for details.

Comment: Modern style is to use `$(…)` in preference to backticks (` … `), and not just because it is hell getting backticks to appear in comments under Markdown.

Answer (score -2):

I think best way is to assign filenames to an array.  According to your code, you just want  `depth = 1` so simple `ls` trick will do the job

```
#!/bin/bash

TOTFILES=($(ls -p $1 | grep -v / | sort -n)

# and you can use the array like this
for file in ${TOTFILES[*]};do 
    echo $file;
done
# leave you to get a subset of the ${ToTFILES}
# refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815/how-to-slice-an-array-in-bash
```

Comment: Please don't encourage people to [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: thanks, accept that downvote, but life is dangerous anyway :)