# Slice array with args from command line - bash

Tags: bash

Trying to slice array while taking args from command prompt as the array items. The problem is that the positional parameters for slicing do not work as I expect. How do I slice array taking params from prompt?

`./arrays.bash awesome cool strong cute awesome`

I want

```
  arr=$@ 
  echo ${arr[*]:0:2} #awesome cool
```

I get

```
  arr=$@ 
  echo ${arr[*]:0:2} # aw
```

I read the post: [How to slice an array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815/how-to-slice-an-array-in-bash)
but I believe my question is different. Seems to be that the difficulty here is that because I am getting my array values from the command prompt, or not, idk. It *does* behave as expected when array is included in the script as a variable. 
This is from learnyoubash so just adjusting the indexes to cut out characters instead of entire values, which does return the correct answer, is not a valid solution to the problem. 
My solution incorrect but working solution https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/2241

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store `$@` in an array you must write:

```
arr=("$@")
```

Without the parentheses `$arr` is just a single string.

Comment: Also, you should almost always use `[@]` with arrays, and double-quote it (e.g. `"${arr[@]:0:2}"`) to avoid trouble with funny characters in the array elements.