# Exporting excess arguments of a bash file to another text file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash file which normally takes 3 arguments normally. There is an extra condition which is invoked when there are more than 3 arguments given. This condition should export the extra arguments to a text file called excess. This is the code I have so far:

```
if [ $# -gt 3]; then
   for ((i = 4; i <= $#; i++)); do
       echo "$i" >> "excess.txt"    
   done
fi
```

Instead of exporting the actual arguments, the loop is exporting the numbers 4,5,6... to the text file.

I'm not quite sure why this is happening seeing that I've used the dollar sign before 'i' in the echo statement.

Comment: I'm sorry the question cut out the if statement I had for some reason, but the problem is in the loop as it is.

Comment: Related: [How to slice an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335815/6862601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use indirect expansion `${!}`:

```
for ((i = 4; i <= $#; i++)); do
    echo "${!i}" >> "excess.txt"
done
```

also, you can do

```
shift 3; echo "$@" >> execss.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one line:

```
printf '%s\n' "${@:4}" > excess.txt
```

`"${@:4}"` expands to `"$4" "$5" "$6" ...`, and the `printf` command has its own loop to output its format string once per argument.