# Insert an element at a certain index in Bash

Tags: bash

I have an array in bash, which is declared as

```
string='var1/var2/var3';
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< $string
```

So the array is `["var1", "var2", "var3"]`

I want to add an element at a specified index and then shift the rest of the elements that already exist.

So the resultant array becomes

`["var1", "newVar", "var2", "var3"]`

I've been trying to do this with and loops but I feel like there's some better more "bash" way of doing this. The array may not be of a fixed length so it needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
declare -a arr=("var1" "var2" "var3")
i=1
arr=("${arr[@]:0:$i}" 'new' "${arr[@]:$i}")
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

result will be:

```
var1 new var2 var3
```

More details: [How to slice an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815/how-to-slice-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: Note that the offset and length parts of `${var:offset:length}` expansion are arithmetic, so the `$` is not strictly required there: `${arr[@]:i}` etc

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorter alternative. The **+=** operator allows overwriting consequent array elements starting from an arbitrary index, so you don't have to update the whole array in this case. See:

```
$ foo=({1..3})
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
$
$ i=1
$ foo+=([i]=bar "${foo[@]:i}")
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="1" [1]="bar" [2]="2" [3]="3")
```